# What is the best way to conditionally apply a class?

Tags: css, angularjs

Lets say you have an array that is rendered in a `ul` with an `li` for each element and a property on the controller called `selectedIndex`. What would be the best way to add a class to the `li` with the index `selectedIndex` in AngularJS?

I am currently duplicating (by hand) the `li` code and adding the class to one of the `li` tags and using `ng-show` and `ng-hide` to show only one `li` per index.

Comment: Answers to this question show that there is more to the templating than {{varname}}. Where can I find documentation of what more there is to templating, such as the ternary operator in a couple of different forms? http://docs.angularjs.org/guide/templates does not seem to explain what templating offers in terms of conditionals etc. besides {{varname.fieldname}}.

Comment: this is so mush useful for me hope it will work for you http://tech-blog.maddyzone.com/javascript/conditionally-apply-classes-in-angularjs

Answer (score 1387, accepted):

If you don't want to put CSS class names into Controller like I do, here is an old trick that I use since pre-v1 days. We can write an expression that evaluates directly to a class name *selected*, no custom directives are necessary:

```
ng:class="{true:'selected', false:''}[$index==selectedIndex]"
```

*Please note the old syntax with colon.*

There is also a new better way of applying classes conditionally, like:

```
ng-class="{selected: $index==selectedIndex}"
```

Angular now supports expressions that return an object. Each property (name) of this object is now considered as a class name and is applied depending on its value.

However these ways are not functionally equal. Here is an example:

```
ng-class="{admin:'enabled', moderator:'disabled', '':'hidden'}[user.role]"
```

We could therefore reuse existing CSS classes by basically mapping a model property to a class name and at the same time keep CSS classes out of Controller code.

Comment: This doesn't remove the old class in v0.10 but it seems to work in v0.9.x

Comment: @respectTheCode Hmm, I havent't had the opportunity to test v0.10 Have to reported an issue?

Comment: OP, that may be the worse way to express the ternary operator I've ever seen.  Have you considered `($index==selectedIndex) ? 'selected' : ''` ?

Comment: @Malvolio AFAIR, ternary operator was not working within angular expressions in v0.9.x . This is more or less a switch.

Comment: ng-class (as of 1/19/2012) now supports an expression that must evaluate to either 1) a string of space-delimited class names, or 
2) and array of class names, or 3) a map/object of class names to boolean values.  So, using 3): ng-class="{selected: $index==selectedIndex}"

Comment: Thanks @Mark, BTW now that I have checked I can say that this method is working in v1. It still useful in some cases. Note that object property names(keys) are not necessarily true or false, it can be anything that you might wanna map to a class name.

Comment: I just want to add, I was having an issue because I was using syntax like
    
    `{classname: '$index === selectedIndex'}`
    
and it wasn't working. When I pushed everything together and used == instead of === it worked.
    
    `{classname: '$index==selectedIndex'}`

Comment: How can I use an expression for the classname too? For example ng-class="{'item-focus-'+focusIndex : focusIndex >= 0}" -- this does not work, but illustrates what I have in mind

Comment: @Casey Unfortunately not all javascript expressions are valid angularjs expressions. Perhaps you could ask for a separate question. Please state your intent too, as you might not even need such expressions.

Comment: My intent is to derive a classname with a variable value when a condition is met. without doing it in the controller, is this possible?

Comment: @Casey, I was asking, what you really want to happen in the end. Deriving class name is probably not your only option. I would gladly try to help if your intent was clear, but I cant think of a reason why you need such capability. That is why I suggested asking a separate question.

Comment: I realize there may be workarounds for my particular use case (which I am already employing), but I'm interested in a solution for the abstract problem -- or knowing definitively that there isn't one.

Comment: @Casey, it is not a workaround if a solution does not necessary have the same problem. Without knowing about your problem, let me tell you what I mean by that. Perhaps you could use two ng-class directives, one for item-focus and another for index. In CSS, you could then check for existence of both classes using something like .item-focus.4 If this solves your issue, I would not consider this as a workaround. It is using right tools for right purposes. If this does not solve your issue, that again means you should ask a separate question.

Comment: The "new" syntax is buggy for me (as of v1.1.5). My code `ng-class="{'favoriteon': favorite > 0 , 'favorite': favorite === 0, '<server value>': favorite < 0}` would correctly evaluate my initial (server) value and then make one correct toggle. The third toggle would break. Seems like a three state switch does not work correctly with this syntax. I had to revert to the "old" array based syntax to achieve the desired result. My code works with: `ng-class="{'1':'favoriteon', '0':'favorite', '-1':'@Model.FavoriteClass'}[favorite]`

Comment: what should I do if I want customize only one of several classes this way? ex.: `active` class in `class="well view active"`

Comment: very useful article http://tech-blog.maddyzone.com/javascript/conditionally-apply-classes-in-angularjs

Comment: {'classname': condition} is work for me (note the ' ').

Comment: on a class name with a hyphen (-) in it you need to use quotes. eg `ng-class="{'my-class':somePotentiallyNullVariable}"`

Answer (score 438):

[ng-class](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.directive:ngClass) supports an expression that must evaluate to either

1. A string of space-delimited class names, or
2. An array of class names, or
3. A map/object of class names to boolean values.

So, using form 3) we can simply write

```
ng-class="{'selected': $index==selectedIndex}"
```

See also [How do I conditionally apply CSS styles in AngularJS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13813254/how-do-i-conditionally-apply-css-styles-in-angularjs) for a broader answer.

---

**Update**: Angular 1.1.5 has added support for a [ternary operator](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/commit/6798fec4390a72b7943a49505f8a245b6016c84b), so if that construct is more familiar to you:

```
ng-class="($index==selectedIndex) ? 'selected' : ''"
```

Comment: +1 for ternary operators (and I need one right now) but 1.1.* is an 'unstable release' where the API is subject to change without notice - as of time of typing. 1.0.* is stable, so I'd be more comfortable going with that for a project to be rolled out next week for 6 months.

Comment: `ng-class="{'selected': $index==selectedIndex}"` works for me

Answer (score 158):

My favorite method is using the ternary expression.

```
ng-class="condition ? 'trueClass' : 'falseClass'"
```

**Note:** Incase you're using a older version of Angular you should use this instead,

```
ng-class="condition && 'trueClass' || 'falseClass'"
```

Comment: This helped me writing this expression: `ng-class="property.name=='timestamp' ? 'property-timestamp' : 'property-'+{{$index}}"`. Could not figure out any other way.

Comment: I am really not finding why my scoped boolean modalFlag is not updating -

ng-class="{'closed': modalFlag , 'open':!modalFlag}"

I am trying to add either closed or open depending on the scoped variable/boolean - if anyone can help I would be very grateful -thank you.

Comment: This was introduced as 1.5 version. https://github.com/angular/angular.js/commit/6798fec4390a72b7943a49505f8a245b6016c84b

Answer (score 53):

I'll add to this, because some of these answers seem out of date. Here's how I do it:

```
<class="ng-class:isSelected">
```

Where 'isSelected' is a javascript variable defined within the scoped angular controller.

To more specifically address your question, here's how you might generate a list with that:

**HTML**

```
<div ng-controller="ListCtrl">  
    <li class="ng-class:item.isSelected" ng-repeat="item in list">   
       {{item.name}}
    </li>  
</div>
```

**JS**

```
function ListCtrl($scope) {    
    $scope.list = [  
        {"name": "Item 1", "isSelected": "active"},  
        {"name": "Item 2", "isSelected": ""}
    ]
}
```

See: http://jsfiddle.net/tTfWM/

See: http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.directive:ngClass

Comment: Whats differents between class="ng-class:item.isSelected" and ng-class="item.isSelected"

Comment: Curious on the use of `ng-class:className` vs just using `class="{{className}}"` ?

Answer (score 48):

Here is a much simpler solution:

```js
function MyControl($scope){
    $scope.values = ["a","b","c","d","e","f"];
    $scope.selectedIndex = -1;
    
    $scope.toggleSelect = function(ind){
        if( ind === $scope.selectedIndex ){
            $scope.selectedIndex = -1;
        } else{
            $scope.selectedIndex = ind;
        }
    }
    
    $scope.getClass = function(ind){
        if( ind === $scope.selectedIndex ){
            return "selected";
        } else{
            return "";
        }
    }
       
    $scope.getButtonLabel = function(ind){
        if( ind === $scope.selectedIndex ){
            return "Deselect";
        } else{
            return "Select";
        }
    }
}
```

```css
.selected {
    color:red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.0.1/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app ng-controller="MyControl">
    <ul>
        <li ng-class="getClass($index)" ng-repeat="value in values" >{{value}} <button ng-click="toggleSelect($index)">{{getButtonLabel($index)}}</button></li>
    </ul>
    <p>Selected: {{selectedIndex}}</p>
</div>
```

Comment: I'd highly recommend to keep your controller clear of CSS stuff. That's a path you don't want to head down.

Comment: Class names belong in the template

Comment: At some point, jsfiddle may miss to pay their bills, or choose to move to another domain, or the responsible people get killed by a bus (see also Bus Factor). So may I ask you to explain what that fiddle does, _within_ your answer? This is also canonical on stack overflow.

Answer (score 27):

I faced a similar problem recently and decided to just create a conditional filter:

```
  angular.module('myFilters', []).
    /**
     * "if" filter
     * Simple filter useful for conditionally applying CSS classes and decouple
     * view from controller 
     */
    filter('if', function() {
      return function(input, value) {
        if (typeof(input) === 'string') {
          input = [input, ''];
        }
        return value? input[0] : input[1];
      };
    });
```

It takes a single argument, which is either a 2-element array or a string, which gets turned into an array that is appended an empty string as the second element:

```
<li ng-repeat="item in products | filter:search | orderBy:orderProp |
  page:pageNum:pageLength" ng-class="'opened'|if:isOpen(item)">
  ...
</li>
```

Comment: me to I just created for exemple a yesNo() filter returning classes 'yes' or 'no' according to a boolean value 1 o 0 :
`filter('yesNo', function() {
      return function(input) {
        // info('yesNo('+ input +')');
        switch(input){
            case '1':
                return ' yes ';
                break;
            default:
                return ' no ';
                break;   
        }
      }
});`

Comment: ng-class can handle a map/object of class names to boolean values, so you could simply write the following:  ng-class="{yes: some_boolean_expression, no: some_other_boolean_expression}"
E.g., ng-class="{yes: input, no: !input}"

Answer (score 21):

If you want to go beyond binary evaluation and keep your CSS out of your controller you can implement a simple filter that evaluates the input against a map object:

```
angular.module('myApp.filters, [])
  .filter('switch', function () { 
      return function (input, map) {
          return map[input] || '';
      }; 
  });
```

This allows you to write your markup like this:

```
<div ng-class="muppets.star|switch:{'Kermit':'green', 'Miss Piggy': 'pink', 'Animal': 'loud'}">
    ...
</div>
```

Comment: Hi @Joe, any ideas how to handle null values? If i pass in null in the input, it wont map its class...

Comment: @user1191559 - you could a 'default' item to the map, then return that value if 'input' is null.

Answer (score 17):

The was I recently did that was doing this:

```
<input type="password"  placeholder="Enter your password"
ng-class="{true: 'form-control isActive', false: 'isNotActive'}[isShowing]">
```

The `isShowing` value is a value that is located on my controller that gets toggled with the click of a button and the parts between the single parenthesis are classes I created in my css file.

EDIT: I would also like to add that codeschool.com has a free course that is sponsored by google on AngularJS that goes over all of this stuff and then some. There is no need to pay for anything, just signup for an account and get going! 
Best of luck to you all!

Comment: Could you provide a fiddle or more code here?  Is `isShowing` an array in the controller then?

Answer (score 15):

Ternary operator [has just been](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md) added to angular parser in **1.1.5**.

So the simplest way to do this is now :

```
ng:class="($index==selectedIndex)? 'selected' : ''"
```

Comment: Also: `class="otherClass ng-class:($index==selectedIndex)? 'selected' : '';"`.

Answer (score 11):

We can **make a function** to manage return class with condition

[image]

```
<script>
    angular.module('myapp', [])
            .controller('ExampleController', ['$scope', function ($scope) {
                $scope.MyColors = ['It is Red', 'It is Yellow', 'It is Blue', 'It is Green', 'It is Gray'];
                $scope.getClass = function (strValue) {
                    switch(strValue) {
                        case "It is Red":return "Red";break;
                        case "It is Yellow":return "Yellow";break;
                        case "It is Blue":return "Blue";break;
                        case "It is Green":return "Green";break;
                        case "It is Gray":return "Gray";break;
                    }
                }
        }]);
</script>
```

And then

```
<body ng-app="myapp" ng-controller="ExampleController">

<h2>AngularJS ng-class if example</h2>
<ul >
    <li ng-repeat="icolor in MyColors" >
        <p ng-class="[getClass(icolor), 'b']">{{icolor}}</p>
    </li>
</ul>
<hr/>
<p>Other way using : ng-class="{'class1' : expression1, 'class2' : expression2,'class3':expression2,...}"</p>
<ul>
    <li ng-repeat="icolor in MyColors">
        <p ng-class="{'Red':icolor=='It is Red','Yellow':icolor=='It is Yellow','Blue':icolor=='It is Blue','Green':icolor=='It is Green','Gray':icolor=='It is Gray'}" class="b">{{icolor}}</p>
    </li>
</ul>
```

You can refer to full code page at [ng-class if example](http://angularjsaz.blogspot.com/2015/09/ng-class-if-example.html)

Answer (score 9):

I am new to Angular but have found this to solve my issue:

```
<i class="icon-download" ng-click="showDetails = ! showDetails" ng-class="{'icon-upload': showDetails}"></i>
```

This will conditionally apply a class based on a var.
It starts off with a **icon-download** as a default, the using ng-class, I check the status of `showDetails` if `true/false` and apply class **icon-upload**. Its working great.

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 9):

This works like a charm ;)

```
<ul class="nav nav-pills" ng-init="selectedType = 'return'">
    <li role="presentation" ng-class="{'active':selectedType === 'return'}"
        ng-click="selectedType = 'return'"><a href="#return">return

    </a></li>
    <li role="presentation" ng-class="{'active':selectedType === 'oneway'}"
        ng-click="selectedType = 'oneway'"><a href="#oneway">oneway
    </a></li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 5):

This will probably get downvoted to oblivion, but here is how I used 1.1.5's ternary operators to switch classes depending on whether a row in a table is the first, middle or last -- except if there is only one row in the table:

```
<span class="attribute-row" ng-class="(restaurant.Attributes.length === 1) || ($first ? 'attribute-first-row': false || $middle ? 'attribute-middle-row': false || $last ? 'attribute-last-row': false)">
</span>
```

Answer (score 5):

This is in my work multiple conditionally judge:

```
<li ng-repeat='eOption in exam.examOptions' ng-class="exam.examTitle.ANSWER_COM==exam.examTitle.RIGHT_ANSWER?(eOption.eoSequence==exam.examTitle.ANSWER_COM?'right':''):eOption.eoSequence==exam.examTitle.ANSWER_COM?'wrong':eOption.eoSequence==exam.examTitle.RIGHT_ANSWER?'right':''">
  <strong>{{eOption.eoSequence}}</strong> &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;|&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
  <span ng-bind-html="eOption.eoName | to_trusted">2020 元</span>
</li>
```

Answer (score 4):

Here is another option that works well when ng-class can't be used (for example when styling SVG):

```
ng-attr-class="{{someBoolean && 'class-when-true' || 'class-when-false' }}"
```

(I think you need to be on latest unstable Angular to use ng-attr-, I'm currently on 1.1.4)

Answer (score 4):

### partial

```
  <div class="col-md-4 text-right">
      <a ng-class="campaign_range === 'thismonth' ? 'btn btn-blue' :  'btn btn-link'" href="#" ng-click='change_range("thismonth")'>This Month</a>
      <a ng-class="campaign_range === 'all' ? 'btn btn-blue' :  'btn btn-link'" href="#" ng-click='change_range("all")'>All Time</a>
  </div>
```

### controller

```
  $scope.campaign_range = "all";
  $scope.change_range = function(range) { 
        if (range === "all")
        {
            $scope.campaign_range = "all"
        }
        else
        {  
            $scope.campaign_range = "thismonth"
        }
  };
```

Answer (score 4):

well i would suggest you to check condition in your controller with a function returning **true** or **false** .

```
<div class="week-wrap" ng-class="{today: getTodayForHighLight(todayDate, day.date)}">{{day.date}}</div>
```

and in your controller check the condition

```
$scope.getTodayForHighLight = function(today, date){
return (today == date);
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Check [this](http://www.codinginsight.com/angularjs-if-else-statement/).

The infamous AngularJS `if|else` statement!!!
When I started using Angularjs, I was a bit surprised that I couldn’t find an if/else statement.

So I was working on a project and I noticed that when using the if/else statement, the condition shows while loading.
You can use ng-cloak to fix this.

```
<div class="ng-cloak">
 <p ng-show="statement">Show this line</span>
 <p ng-hide="statement">Show this line instead</span>
</div>
```

`.ng-cloak { display: none }`

Thanks amadou

Answer (score 3):

If you are using angular **pre v1.1.5** *(i.e. no ternary operator)* and you still want an equivalent way to set a value in **both** conditions you can do something like this:

```
ng-class="{'class1':item.isReadOnly == false, 'class2':item.isReadOnly == true}"
```

Answer (score 3):

If you having a common class that is applied to many elements you can create a custom directive that will add that class like ng-show/ng-hide.

This directive will add the class 'active' to the button if it's clicked

```
module.directive('ngActive',  ['$animate', function($animate) {
  return function(scope, element, attr) {
    scope.$watch(attr.ngActive, function ngActiveWatchAction(value){
      $animate[value ? 'addClass' : 'removeClass'](element, 'active');
    });
  };
}]);
```

More info

Answer (score 3):

Just adding something that worked for me today, after much searching...

```
<div class="form-group" ng-class="{true: 'has-error'}[ctrl.submitted && myForm.myField.$error.required]">
```

Hope this assists in your successful development.

=)

[Undocumented Expression Syntax : Great Website Link... =)](http://blog.xebia.com/2014/01/31/ngclass-expressions-in-angularjs/)

Comment: Check out the accepted answer. It is doing the same thing and gives more examples.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [this](https://www.npmjs.com/package/dynamic-class-list) npm package. It handles everything and has options for static and conditional classes based on a variable or a function.

```
// Support for string arguments
getClassNames('class1', 'class2');

// support for Object
getClassNames({class1: true, class2 : false});

// support for all type of data
getClassNames('class1', 'class2', ['class3', 'class4'], { 
    class5 : function() { return false; },
    class6 : function() { return true; }
});

<div className={getClassNames({class1: true, class2 : false})} />
```

Answer (score 0):

I understand this question id for angular, but if anyone is using React or a React-Based Framework (Amplify, NextJS, Serverless, etc.) The solution is significantly easier. The most performant way is with a ternary operator like so:

```
<div className={condition ? "classnameiftrue" : "classnameiffalse"}>
```

You can use this strategy to animate the tree if using `useState()` as each time the state changes it will reload that conditional with the new value.