# angularjs if statements?

Tags: if-statement, angularjs

So I'm running through the tutorial for AngularJS:

I have an array defined in the controller and i'm returning different points in the array by calling when i'm looping through ng-repeat {{feature.name}} {{feature.description}}

What i don't understand is lets say i have a third point in the array called "importance" and it's a number from 1 to 10. I don't want to display that number in the html but what i do want to do is apply a different color to the feature if that "importance" number in the array is 10 vs 1

so how do i write an if statement to do this:

i.e.

```
<p style="**insert if statement: {{if feature.importance == 10}} color:red; {{/if}} **">{{feature.description}}</p>
```

no idea if that's right but that's what i want to do

Comment: real iif: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14164371/inline-conditionals-in-angular-js/14165488#14165488

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This first one is a directive that evaluates whether something should be in the DOM only once and adds no watch listeners to the page:

```
angular.module('setIf',[]).directive('setIf',function () {
    return {
      transclude: 'element',
      priority: 1000,
      terminal: true,
      restrict: 'A',
      compile: function (element, attr, linker) {
        return function (scope, iterStartElement, attr) {
          if(attr.waitFor) {
            var wait = scope.$watch(attr.waitFor,function(nv,ov){
              if(nv) {
                build();
                wait();
              }
            });
          } else {
            build();
          }

          function build() {
            iterStartElement[0].doNotMove = true;
            var expression = attr.setIf;
            var value = scope.$eval(expression);
            if (value) {
              linker(scope, function (clone) {
                iterStartElement.after(clone);
                clone.removeAttr('set-if');
                clone.removeAttr('wait-for');
              });
            }
          }
        };
      }
    };
  });
```

This second one is a directive that conditionally applies attributes to elements only once without watch listeners:

i.e.

```
<div set-attr="{ data-id : post.id, data-name : { value : post.name, condition : post.name != 'FOO' } }"></div>

angular.module('setAttr',[]).directive('setAttr', function() {
  return {
    restrict: 'A',
    priority: 100,
    link: function(scope,elem,attrs) {
      if(attrs.setAttr.indexOf('{') != -1 && attrs.setAttr.indexOf('}') != -1) {
      //you could just angular.isObject(scope.$eval(attrs.setAttr)) for the above but I needed it this way
        var data = scope.$eval(attrs.setAttr);

        angular.forEach(data, function(v,k){

          if(angular.isObject(v)) {
            if(v.value && v.condition) {
                elem.attr(k,v.value);
                elem.removeAttr('set-attr');
            }
          } else {
            elem.attr(k,v);
            elem.removeAttr('set-attr');
          }
        });
      }
    }
  }
});
```

Of course your can use dynamic versions built into angular:

```
<div ng-class="{ 'myclass' : item.iscool }"></div>
```

You can also use the new ng-if added by angularjs which basically replaces ui-if created by the angularui team these will conditionally add and remove things from the DOM and add watch listeners to keep evaluating:

```
<div ng-if="item.iscool"></div>
```

Answer (score 11):

I do not think there is `if` statement available.
For your styling purpose, `ng-class` can be used.

```
<p ng-class="{important: feature.importance == 10 }">
```

`ng-switch` is also convenient.

-- update --

take a look at:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/18021855/1238847

angular1.2.0RC seems to have ng-if support.

Comment: you can do something like this: `ng-class="border_{{4 > x}}"`. The above syntax doesn't work as written.

Comment: Hi, I think the answer needs an update, look at my post at the bottom.

Answer (score 7):

Actually *there is* a ternary operator in Angular 1.2.0.

```
<p style="{{feature.importance == 10 ? 'color:red' : ''}}">{{feature.description}}</p>
```

Answer (score 6):

I think the answer needs an update.

Previously you could use ngIf directive from AngularUI project (code [here](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/blob/master/src/ng/directive/ngIf.js) if you still want to download it), bad news is that it's not maintained any more.

The good news is that it has been added to the official AngularJS repo ([unstable branch](https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.1.5/angular.js)) and soon will be available in the [stable one](https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.0.7/angular.js).

```
<div ng-if="something"> Foo bar </div>
```

Will not just hide the `DIV` element, but remove it from DOM as well (when something is falsy).

Answer (score 3):

ng-class is probably the best answer to your issue, but AngularUI has an "if" directive:

http://angular-ui.github.com/

search for:
Remove elements from the DOM completely instead of just hiding it.

I used "ui-if" to decide if I should render a data value as a label or an input, relative to the current month:

```
<tbody id="allocationTableBody">
    <tr ng-repeat="a in data.allocations">
        <td>{{a.monthAbrv}}</td>
        <td ui-if="$index < currentMonth">{{a.amounts[0]}}</td>
    </tr>
</tbody>
```

Answer (score 3):

In the case where your priority would be a label, you could create a switch filter to use inside of ng-class as shown in a previous SO answer : https://stackoverflow.com/a/8309832/1036025 (for the switch filter code)

```
<p ng-class="feature.importance|switch:{'Urgent':'red', 'Warning': 'orange', 'Normal': 'green'}">...</p>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can also try this line of code below

```
<div class="{{is_foo && foo.bar}}">
```

which shows foo.bar if is_foo is true.

Answer (score 1):

What also works is:

```
<span>{{ varWithValue || 'If empty use this string' }}</span>
```