# ng-repeat and ui-if

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui

When I want to use ui-if (anguluarUi) with ng-repeat (and I think it would be most useful there) I Get an error:

```
Error: Multiple directives [uiIf, ngRepeat] asking for transclusion on: <!-- uiIf: oConnection.aOptions -->
```

Is there any way to combine those two?

**Edit:**

```
<ng-repeat><div ui-if>...
```

Is not possible (for now) unfortunately.

I know that I can combine ng-show and ng-repeat, but it's not the same.

I also don't want to put the ui-if outside of the repeat, as I want to use the values of the repeat for the condition.

Comment: Put ui-if in the child elements?

Comment: That kinda defeats the purpose of using ui-if for consistent styling.

Comment: I don't think so, why? Besides, conditionally changing the dom structure in ngRepeat would have a performance hit. You can either use ngShow or just filter the ngRepeat source.

Comment: Also, to your question: Two directives cannot ask for transclusion, template replace and isolated scope on the same element because they do conflict with each other, how would angular decide which directive to follow? If you are going to use ui-if then you are stuck with using it either outside of ngRepeat or inside it but not on the same element

Comment: For using nth:child and :first-child consistently for example.

Comment: @fastreload: Thx for the explanation. I thought this might be the case. Would be nice to have a.... Well there are filter-functions. I think I'm gonna stick with that.

Comment: You can also conditionally apply a class to a element with ngClass, and combine that with the ngRepeat's indexer. e.g. `ng-class="{blueBg: $index % 2 == 0}"`

Comment: Use a filter like @joshkurz suggests, or/and ngClass if that's what you need.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think that a filter should be used instead of ui-if.

Answer (score 3):

**ui-if was removed** at least from latest version angular-ui but since **angular 1.1.5** you have **ng-if** build-in.