# Hide element if angular attribute is empty

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, angularjs

I have an image element that is getting its path from an attribute I have on my angular object. However if this (imagePath) is empty I get a broken image.  I would like to not render the image if the attribute is empty however I do not see a way to do this.  Any ideas?

```
<img width="50px" src="/resources/img/products/{{current.manufacturerImage.imagePath}}">
```

Comment: real iif: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14164371/inline-conditionals-in-angular-js/14165488#14165488

Answer (score 21, accepted):

You want to check out [`ngHide`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngHide) directive.

So your code would look something like.

```
<img width="50px" ng-hide="current.manufacturerImage.imagePath == ''" 
src="/resources/img/products/{{current.manufacturerImage.imagePath}}">
```

Alternatively, you could also try the suggestion by **darkporter**

```
<img width="50px" ng-show="current.manufacturerImage.imagePath" 
src="/resources/img/products/{{current.manufacturerImage.imagePath}}">
```

You could also update this to check if the object is null or undefined then hide the element.

Comment: Pretty sure ng-hide/show don't need proper booleans and can use truthiness. I'd do `ng-show="current.manufacturerImage.imagePath"`

Comment: @darkporter, be careful with this approach with any value that can be 0 though, like an ID, as this could be parsed incorrectly as falsy.

Answer (score 1):

Alternatively **ngIf** directive can be used as below:

```
<img width="50px" *ngIf="current.manufacturerImage.imagePath !== ''" 
src="/resources/img/products/{{current.manufacturerImage.imagePath}}">
```

Comment: this is now the correct answer. Thank you for keeping it updated.

Answer (score 0):

This suggestion wouldn't work for me because I was generating my image links based on a users role. The user had a role, but that didn't mean they had an image associated with it.

So I created a directive:

```
angular.module('hideEmptyImages', [])
.directive('hideEmptyImage',function() {
    return {
        Restrict: 'AE',
        Link: function (scope, elem, attrs) {
            elem.error(function() {
                elem.hide();
            });
        }
    };
});
```

So:

```
<img hide-empty-image width="50px" src="/resources/img/products/{{current.manufacturerImage.imagePath}}">
```

will not show if the .imagePath is empty or if there simply isn't an associated image.