# How to show/hide if variable is null

Tags: angularjs

I'm wanting to show/hide a div based on whether a variable is null or not.

```
<div ng-show="myvar"></div>
```

Note: the variable in my case is an object.

A very simple question, but I can't seem to make it work.

Thanks.

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14164371/inline-conditionals-in-angular-js

Comment: myvar == null perhaps

Comment: What non-null values does `myvar` assume? `ng-show` will show for any [truthy](http://www.sitepoint.com/javascript-truthy-falsy/) value, so as long as `myvar` isn't `false`, `null`, `undefined`, `0`, the empty string or `NaN` it should work. Please post some more code for context.

Comment: To clarify, the above example does work, my code did not for unrelated reasons. If mylar is false, null or has never been used before (i.e. $scope.myvar or $rootScope.myvar never called), the div will not show. Once any value has been assigned to it, the div will show, except if the value is specifically false.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

To clarify, the above example does work, my code in the example did not work for unrelated reasons.

If myvar is false, null or has never been used before (i.e. $scope.myvar or $rootScope.myvar never called), the div will not show. Once any value has been assigned to it, the div will show, except if the value is specifically false.

**The following will cause the div to show:**

```
$scope.myvar = "Hello World";
```

or

```
$scope.myvar = true;
```

**The following will hide the div:**

```
$scope.myvar = null;
```

or

```
$scope.myvar = false;
```

Answer (score 205):

```
<div ng-hide="myvar == null"></div>
```

or

```
<div ng-show="myvar != null"></div>
```

Comment: It is a good practise to use `<div ng-hide="myvar == null"></div>` instead of `<div ng-show="myvar != null"></div>`. It's more readable.

Comment: @maicher That really depends on the context

Comment: does ng-show translates the expression as `$scope.myvar != $scope.null` or `$scope.myvar != null`? (posted question here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31387397 )

Comment: Angular will use the javascript null. You really don't want to start adding null to scope anyway as null should always be null (plus angular will ignore the $scope.null it if used in an expression).

Answer (score 2):

In this case, myvar should be a boolean value. If this variable is true, it will show the div, if it's false.. It will hide.

Check [this](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.directive%3angShow) out.

Comment: So are you saying that it will only work if `myvar` is boolean?

Comment: I'm wanting to find a solution where myvar is an object. Thanks.

Comment: It should be a truthy or falsy.

Comment: Paul, what's your object return?