# Does angularjs treates null as $scope.null?

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-scope

Example for the question

```
<div ng-show="bar !== null">hello</div>
```

Is this evaluated in the scope as

```
$scope.bar !== null
```

or is it as this?

```
$scope.bar !== $scope.null
```

Note that in last case, $scope.null would be undefined and the example would seem to work right.

**Bonus:**

if bar = null then this happens

```
// this does not work (shows hello)
<div ng-show="bar !== null">hello</div>
```

does not give the same result as

```
// this works ok (does not show hello)
<div ng-show="bar != null">hello</div>
```

why does that happen?

Comment: if you are setting `bar` as boolean or object or string/number that isn't "0" just need `ng-show="bar"`

Comment: `bar` is coming from a json api, and can be not defined (`undefined`), `null` or have a value

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, Angular [recognizes](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/blob/71fc3f4fa0cd12eff335d57efed7c033554749f4/src/ng/parse.js#L594) some JS primitives in expressions, and `null` is among them.

Answer (score 6):

Angular uses advanced parser ([$parse](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/blob/master/src/ng/parse.js) service) in order to process and evaluate attribute expressions as if they were javascript code. When it works it will rank `null` higher priority over scope property with the same name. It means that in expressions like

```
ng-show="bar !== null"
```

Angular will indeed treat `null` as primitive `null` value.

It is however easy to instruct Angular that you want to use scope property and not `null` primitive. In this case you need to use bracket notation:

```html
ng-show="bar !== this['null']"
```

And final note. While it's possible to use properties with names like `null`, `undefined` etc, I would not recommend it because it's confusing and you need to go with verbose bracket syntax.

Comment: You don't even need brackets, the parser should be ok with `this.null`.

Comment: It seems like `=== null` is not working as in console, but `== null` is.

Answer (score 1):

`null` in an angular expression is the Javascript `null` not as `$scope.null`. It's easy to check that using the expression evaluation example at https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/expression

I just tried entering 4 expressions:

```
null=1 =>
null =>
x=1 => 1
x => 1
```

and as you can see while you can set and access a variable such as `x`, trying to use `null` as a variable doesn't work in the angular expression evaluator.

Answer (score 1):

As estus says, Angular recognizes `null`.

If you want, you can do this in your controller: Check if the value is `null` (`undefined` will return `false`)

```
var myApp = angular.module('myApp',[]);
function MyCtrl($scope) {
    $scope.bar = 'notNull';
    $scope.isNull = function(val) {
        return val === null;
        //If you want to check undefined as well, use :
        //return angular.isUndefined(val) || val === null;
    };
}

<div ng-controller="MyCtrl">
    <span ng-show="!isNull(bar)">Hello, {{bar}}!</span>
</div>
```