# If any of those properties comes null, then don't show the item

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am working with Angularjs and I am receiving an array of objects like this:

```
{
  "_id": 310243,
  "name": "Five Star Babies: Inside the Portland Hospital",
  "airsDayOfWeek": "Wednesday",
  "airsTime": "21:00",
  "firstAired": "2016-04-13T00:00:00.000Z",
  "network": "BBC Two",
  "overview": "An exclusive glimpse inside the UK's only private maternity hospital.\r\n",
  "rating": null,
  "ratingCount": 0,
  "status": "Continuing",
  "poster": "/someImage/path",
  "subscribers": []
}
```

actually that object comes from this function:

```
  $scope.shows = Show.query(); // returns an array
  _.forEach($scope.shows, function(item) {
    if (item.rating === null) {
      console.log(angular.toJson(item, 'pretty'));
    }
  })
```

as you see there I need that if the property "rating" or "poster" comes in `null`, then don't display the element in the view, which this is the proper case, as you see, rating comes in `null` so I need to hide the whole element.

View:

```
    <div ng-repeat="show in shows | filter:query | orderBy:'rating':true">
      <a href="/shows/{{show._id}}">
        <img ng-src="{{show.poster}}" width="100%"/>
      </a>
      <div>
        <a href="/shows/{{show._id}}">{{show.name}}</a>
        <p>
          Episodes: {{show.episodes.length}} <br>
          <span>Rating: {{show.rating}}</span>
        </p>
      </div>
    </div>
```

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 2):

Seems like you can just filter your array for the values you want.

```
$scope.shows = Show.query().filter(function(val) {
    if (val.rating !== null && val.poster !== null) return val;
});
```

That'll give you an array sans the shows that don't have a rating / poster.

Answer (score 0):

try this  :

```
<div ng-repeat="show in shows | filter:query | orderBy:'rating':true" ng-hide="show.rating == null || show.poster == null">
      <a href="/shows/{{show._id}}">
        <img ng-src="{{show.poster}}" width="100%"/>
      </a>
      <div>
        <a href="/shows/{{show._id}}">{{show.name}}</a>
        <p>
          Episodes: {{show.episodes.length}} <br>
          <span>Rating: {{show.rating}}</span>
        </p>
      </div>
    </div>
```

adding `ng-hide="show.rating == null || show.poster == null"` with ng-repeat

You may look into this ques too  : [How to show/hide if variable is null](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21391667/how-to-show-hide-if-variable-is-null)