# Angular JS cleanest way to conditionally append string to tag attribute

Tags: javascript, angularjs, if-statement, href, angularjs-ng-href

I have a very newbie question about angularJS:

I have two `<a>` tag very similar to show their `href` depends only if the variable `foo` is set:

**if foo == null:**

```
<a ng-href="#/bar/{{col.slug}}">{{col.title}}</a>
```

**else**

```
<a ng-href="#/{{foo}}/bar/{{col.slug}}">{{col.title}}</a>
```

As you can see the tags are pretty the same except for the `foo` variable appended at the beginning of the url.

I know there are commands like `ng-show` and `ng-hide`, `ng-if` or [ternary operation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14164371/inline-conditionals-in-angular-js).

How to make this operation in the cleanest way?

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can condition your code:

```
<a ng-href="#/{{ foo != null ? foo + '/' : ''}}bar/{{col.slug}}">{{col.title}}</a>
```

Or you can use ngShow:

```
   <a ng-show="foo == null" ng-href="#/bar/{{col.slug}}">{{col.title}}</a>
   <a ng-show="foo != null" ng-href="#/{{foo}}/bar/{{col.slug}}">{{col.title}}</a>
```

I prefer inline condition, find it more redable

Answer (score 0):

The less data that you send to the browser the better.

```
 <a ng-href="#/{{ !!foo ? foo + '/' : '/'}}bar/{{col.slug}}">{{col.title}}
```