# How to Use Ternary With ng-if?

Tags: angularjs

For example, I want to show the element if `$scope.test === 'hi"`. How do I achieve this?

I tried this:

```
<div ng-if = " {{test}} == 'hi' ? true : false "> 
  Show this if $scope.test is equal to 'hi' 
</div>
```

Example [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14164371/inline-conditionals-in-angular-js) doesn't seem to work. [My fail plunker.](http://plnkr.co/edit/3XHe1Ngw1Ntv5FCTBJwA?p=preview)

Comment: Are you using angular 1.0.5 on purpose? Here is a working plunk with 1.4 http://plnkr.co/edit/3XHe1Ngw1Ntv5FCTBJwA?p=preview

Comment: Thanks seb. And no, I just googled an angular plunk because I was too lazy to write "ng-app = 'blah'" and 'ng-controller = 'blah2' ". Not even being sarcastic. We need some default plunk templates to start from.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need a ternary for that since `ng-if` expects a boolean. This will do:

```
<div ng-if = "test == 'hi'"> 
  Show this if $scope.test is equal to 'hi' 
</div>
```

You can still use ternaries if you wish, you just don't need to interpolate the variable: `test == 'hi' ? true : false`

---

The issue is with your really old Angular version. See it working with 1.3: http://plnkr.co/edit/cKZkOe1O4EBiIWeirlZ2?p=preview

Comment: It still shows up when it's 'bye': http://plnkr.co/edit/3XHe1Ngw1Ntv5FCTBJwA?p=preview

Comment: Hmmm, let me check, could be the Angular version.

Comment: Yup, Angular version: http://plnkr.co/edit/cKZkOe1O4EBiIWeirlZ2?p=preview Try not to go below v**1.3**

Comment: How about: ng-if="isEqual(test, 'hi')"   and create function isEqual(a, b){return a == b;}

Comment: @num8er The problem is with the angular version, the code I wrote above works.

Comment: Weird. i thought we had 1.4.x on our dev. Anyway, my mistake with the plunker. Thank you, accepting answer in a second.

Comment: Yeah, you probably misread 1.0.4. You're welcome, glad we figured it out.

Comment: @Shomz agree with You, many times I do like Your code. I though maybe something buggy with angular.

Comment: @Shomz: Got it fixed in my actual code too. It was a stupid mistake but I started second guessing myself. So much easier when there is a working plunk and you KNOW you are just making some dumb mistake. Ty again.

Comment: Yeah, it's always easier with a small isolated example. You're welcome, now we know not to mess with ng-ifs on old Angular versions. :)

Answer (score 1):

Um. You don't use `{{}}` in the `ng-if`.

```
<div ng-if = " test == 'hi'"> 
Show this if $scope.test is equal to 'hi' 
</div>
```

Above works

---

**EDIT**

This is failing in your plunker because
The ng-if directive was provided after angular 1.1.5, you are using 1.0.5.

Working version

http://plnkr.co/edit/3XHe1Ngw1Ntv5FCTBJwA

Comment: It's failing in my code and on another editor too. It was the first thing I tried before googling for a solution.

Comment: I am accepting Shomz answer because he was first, but thank you very much for the help, upvoted.

Answer (score -3):

You don't need ternary expressions here, just use `ng-show`.

```
<div ng-show="test"></div>
```