# Angular ternary operator with html output

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Is it possible to render the output from a ternary operator as html?

```
{{ boolA ? 'Some text' : '&lt;i class=\"fa fa-check\"&gt;&lt;/i&gt;' }}
```

Also tried to modify a inline if/else directive from a [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14164371/inline-conditionals-in-angular-js) but can't get this to work either.

```
.filter('iif', ['$sce', function ($sce) {
    return function (input, trueValue, falseValue) {
        return $sce.trustAs('html', input ? trueValue : falseValue);
    }
}])
```

Comment: Yes. it is possible to render. Have you written `ng-bind-html` in your html?

Comment: Which angular version are you using?

Comment: why don't you do all this logic inside your controller ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, Use ng-bind-html like this :

`<span ng-bind-html=" your_condition ? 'html_if_true' : 'html_if_false' "></span>`

Replace values according to your requirements.

Comment: Perfect, thanks. Then I can use angle brackets as well and just escape the quotes.