# How should I approach the logic for writing the code for a more complex ng-model feature?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, logic

First, let me explain the effect I am looking for:

Layout:

- Header at the top of the page that says "Choose between...".
- Two input boxes below, input1 and input2

Effect

- If the user begins typing first in [choice1] in input1, the header auto-updates and says "Choose between [choice 1] and..."
- If the user begins typing first in [choice2] in input2, the header auto-updates and says "Choose between ___ and [choice2]"
- If the user has already written in one input and begins writing in the other input, the header auto-updates and says "Choose between [choice1] and [choice2]".

Now, I have already written the angular-js code to achieve this. I am not looking for an answer on *how* to achieve the effect. Instead, I want to know the **logic** for the **best** way to achieve this effect because I think the way I did it could be improved.

Finally, here is the logic I used:

1. Create 4 divs with 4 ng-switch-when properties. Each div contains a header. First div contains header with "Choose between..." written on it. Second div contains header with "Choose between [input1text] and..." written on it. Third div contains a header with "Choose between ___ and [input2text]" written on it. Final div has "Choose between [input1text] and [input2text]" written on it. Each div has an ng-switch-when property, they are: "not-pressed", "first-pressed", "second-pressed", and "both-pressed", respectively
2. If someone starts typing in input1, I see if either second-pressed state or both-pressed state is currently active. If one is, I set the state to both-pressed. Otherwise, I set the state to first-pressed.
3. If someone starts typing in input2, I see if either first-pressed state or both-pressed state is currently active. If one is, I set the state to both-pressed. Otherwise, I set the state to second-pressed.

I think the way I wrote it is really clunky and messy and I'd like an opinion on if there is a better way to apprach the logic to this feature. Again, I am **not looking for code**. I just want to see if there is better logic.

Answer (score 0):

I would assign ng-model to each of the inputs. Then have three divs for each header each referencing the required ng-model (choice1, choice 2 and both). I would then use ng-if on each of the three divs to test if the ng-model was empty for either choice or not.

Answer (score 0):

- I would only have 2 'div', in the `ng-switch-when` block.
- `choice1` and `choice2` are part of `ng-model`
- `ng-switch on` checks whether `choice1` or `choice2` is not an empty string. This means: `choice1` is not empty, or `choice2` is not empty, or `choice1` and `choice2` are not empty
- `ng-switch-when = true` then renders. Note as least one of the choices is entered.

  ```
  <div> 
    <h2> Choose between {{choice1 === "" ? "____" : choice1}} and {{choice2 === "" ? "..." : choice2}} </h2> 
  </div>
  ```
- `ng-switch-default` would render the header as `Choose between ...`

Edit: 
Actually, I think it's better to have a `div` as a wrapper outside the `ng-switch`, then renders only inner element. It seems like regardless of of the values of the inputs, you will always show the header.

Comment: Do the double brackets in angular allow you to have logic like that?

Comment: it depends on which angular version you use, it works on Angular version greater than 1.1.4 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14164371/inline-conditionals-in-angular-js