# angularjs ng-class method is getting invoked multiple times

Tags: javascript, angularjs

In this example, i got 2 ng-class, each calling different controller method, for some reason each method get called 3 times, Any idea? Possible bug?

```
var navList = angular.module('navList', []);

navList.controller('navCtrl', ['$scope', '$location', function ($scope, $location) {
    $scope.firstClass = function () {
        console.log('firstClass');
        return 'label label-success' ;
    };     
    $scope.secondClass = function () {
        console.log('secondClass');
        return 'label' ;
    };     

}]);
```

http://jsfiddle.net/uDPHL/72/

Thanks

Comment: If your goal is to have conditional classes for your labels, have a look at this SO post: http://stackoverflow.com/a/15664427/1036025

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It is not a bug.  When Angular compiles something like `ng-class="firstClass()"`, it sets up a $watch for it. A digest loop may evaluate each $watch multiple times:

> Angular enters the $digest loop. The loop is made up of two smaller loops which process $evalAsync queue and the $watch list. The $digest loop keeps iterating until the model stabilizes, which means that the $evalAsync queue is empty and the $watch list does not detect any changes. -- [Overview doc](http://docs.angularjs.org/guide/concepts#runtime)

Also

> After a watcher is registered with the scope, the listener fn is called asynchronously (via $evalAsync) to initialize the watcher. In rare cases, this is undesirable because the listener is called when the result of watchExpression didn't change. -- [$watch docs](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.%24rootScope.Scope#%24watch)

So, at least two times is expected.