# How do I conditionally apply CSS styles in AngularJS?

Tags: css, angularjs

Q1. Suppose I want to alter the look of each "item" that a user marks for deletion before the main "delete" button is pressed.  (This immediate visual feedback should eliminate the need for the proverbial "are you sure?" dialog box.) The user will check checkboxes to indicate which items should be deleted.  If a checkbox is unchecked, that item should revert back to its normal look.

What's the best way to apply or remove the CSS styling?

Q2. Suppose I want to allow each user to personalize how my site is presented.  E.g., select from a fixed set of font sizes, allow user-definable foreground and background colors, etc.

What's the best way to apply the CSS styling the user selects/inputs?

Comment: useful article http://tech-blog.maddyzone.com/javascript/conditionally-apply-classes-in-angularjs

Answer (score 488, accepted):

Angular provides a number of built-in directives for manipulating CSS styling conditionally/dynamically:

- **[ng-class](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngClass)** - use when the set of CSS styles is static/known ahead of time
- **[ng-style](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngStyle)** - use when you can't define a CSS class because the style values may change dynamically.  Think programmable control of the style values.
- **[ng-show](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngShow)** and **[ng-hide](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngHide)** - use if you only need to show or hide something (modifies CSS)
- **[ng-if](http://code.angularjs.org/1.1.5/docs/api/ng.directive:ngIf)** - new in version 1.1.5, use instead of the more verbose ng-switch if you only need to check for a single condition (modifies DOM)
- **[ng-switch](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngSwitch)** - use instead of using several mutually exclusive ng-shows (modifies DOM)
- **[ng-disabled](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngDisabled)** and **[ng-readonly](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngReadonly)** - use to restrict form element behavior
- **[ng-animate](http://code.angularjs.org/1.1.4/docs/api/ng.directive:ngAnimate)** - new in version 1.1.4, use to add CSS3 transitions/animations

The normal "Angular way" involves tying a model/scope property to a UI element that will accept user input/manipulation (i.e., use ng-model), and then associating that model property to one of the built-in directives mentioned above.

When the user changes the UI, Angular will automatically update the associated elements on the page.

---

Q1 sounds like a good case for ng-class -- the CSS styling can be captured in a class.

**ng-class** accepts an "expression" that must evaluate to one of the following:

1. a string of space-delimited class names
2. an array of class names
3. a map/object of class names to boolean values

Assuming your items are displayed using ng-repeat over some array model, and that when the checkbox for an item is checked you want to apply the `pending-delete` class:

```
<div ng-repeat="item in items" ng-class="{'pending-delete': item.checked}">
   ... HTML to display the item ...
   <input type="checkbox" ng-model="item.checked">
</div>
```

Above, we used ng-class expression type #3 - a map/object of class names to boolean values.

---

Q2 sounds like a good case for ng-style -- the CSS styling is dynamic, so we can't define a class for this.

**ng-style** accepts an "expression" that must evaluate to:

1. an map/object of CSS style names to CSS values

For a contrived example, suppose the user can type in a color name into a texbox for the background color (a jQuery color picker would be much nicer):

```
<div class="main-body" ng-style="{color: myColor}">
   ...
   <input type="text" ng-model="myColor" placeholder="enter a color name">
```

---

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mrajcok/eTTZj/) for both of the above.

The fiddle also contains an example of **ng-show** and **ng-hide**.  If a checkbox is checked, in addition to the background-color turning pink, some text is shown.  If 'red' is entered in the textbox, a div becomes hidden.

Comment: This answer is terrific! Would you be willing to show me via jsfiddle what the difference would be if the click event was changing/adding a class on an area that wasn't the clicked element? Say a div elsewhere on the page.

Comment: it is useful article http://tech-blog.maddyzone.com/javascript/conditionally-apply-classes-in-angularjs

Comment: Great anwser. Btw, have you ever tried applying angular filter to ng-style ?

Comment: I suggest adding an additional option related to Q2 that I just added in my recent answer to this question.

Answer (score 104):

I have found problems when applying classes inside **table** elements when I had one class already applied to the whole table (for example, a color applied to the odd rows `<myClass tbody tr:nth-child(even) td>`). It seems that when you inspect the element with **Developer Tools**, the `element.style` has no style assigned. So instead of using `ng-class`, I have tried using `ng-style`, and in this case, the new CSS attribute does appear inside `element.style`. This code works great for me:

```
<tr ng-repeat="element in collection">

    [...amazing code...]

    <td ng-style="myvar === 0 && {'background-color': 'red'} ||
                  myvar === 1 && {'background-color': 'green'} ||
                  myvar === 2 && {'background-color': 'yellow'}">{{ myvar }}</td>

    [...more amazing code...]

</tr>
```

**Myvar** is what I am evaluating, and in each case I apply a style to each `<td>` depending on **myvar** value, that overwrites the current style applied by the CSS class for the whole table.

**UPDATE**

If you want to apply a class to the table for example, when visiting a page or in other cases, you can use this structure:

```
<li ng-class="{ active: isActive('/route_a') || isActive('/route_b')}">
```

Basically, what we need to activate a **ng-class** is the class to apply and a true or false statement. **True** applies the class and **false** doesn't. So here we have two checks of the route of the page and an **OR** between them, so if we are in `/route_a` **OR** we are in `route_b`, the **active** class will be applied.

This works just having a logic function on the right that returns true or false.

So in the first example, **ng-style** is conditioned by three statements. If all of them are false, no style is applied, but following our logic, at least one is going to be applied, so, the logic expression will check which variable comparison is true and because a non empty array is always true, that will left an array as return and with only one true, considering we are using **OR** for the whole response, the style remaining will be applied.

By the way, I forgot to give you the function isActive():

```
$rootScope.isActive = function(viewLocation) {
    return viewLocation === $location.path();
};
```

**NEW UPDATE**

Here you have something I find really useful. When you need to apply a class depending on the value of a variable, for example, an icon depending on the contents of the `div`, you can use the following code (very useful in `ng-repeat`):

```
<i class="fa" ng-class="{ 'fa-github'   : type === 0,
                          'fa-linkedin' : type === 1,
                          'fa-skype'    : type === 2,
                          'fa-google'   : type === 3 }"></i>
```

> Icons from [Font Awesome](http://fortawesome.github.io/Font-Awesome/)

Comment: what a strange syntax, && should mean AND, like in any other c inspired language

Comment: @PizzaiolaGorgonzola && does mean AND and || does mean OR. It's a clever hack using the short-circuit logic almost as a case/switch statement...

Comment: Thanks mit. I didn't realized of that detail.

Comment: The new update section worked like a charm! +1 for it!

Comment: used the example of ng-class as mentioned in New Update, worked pretty well for me. Pretty sleek

Answer (score 34):

This works well when ng-class can't be used (for example when styling SVG):

```
ng-attr-class="{{someBoolean && 'class-when-true' || 'class-when-false' }}"
```

(I think you need to be on latest unstable Angular to use ng-attr-, I'm currently on 1.1.4)

I have published an article on working with AngularJS+SVG. It talks about this issue and numerous others. http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/709340/Implementing-a-Flowchart-with-SVG-and-AngularJS

Comment: I don't see any mention of ng-attr in the [1.1.4 docs](http://code.angularjs.org/1.1.4/docs/api/) -- do you have a link?

Comment: Sorry don't have a link.  I found out about it by following the Angular forums, although I can't remember the exact page sorry.

Comment: The latest docs (v1.2) describe `ng-attr-` on the [directives page](http://docs.angularjs.org/guide/directive), section _ngAttr attribute bindings_.

Comment: With 1.2, this becomes a great answer.  `ng-class` doesn't let you perform logic, but `ng-attr-class` does.  They both have their uses, but I can bet a lot of developers will be looking for `ng-attr-class`.

Comment: I got this to work well when other solutions provided here failed.  Thank you.

Answer (score 14):

```
span class="circle circle-{{selectcss(document.Extension)}}">
```

and code

```
$scope.selectcss = function (data) {
    if (data == '.pdf')
        return 'circle circle-pdf';
    else
        return 'circle circle-small';
};
```

css

```
.circle-pdf {
    width: 24px;
    height: 24px;
    font-size: 16px;
    font-weight: 700;
    padding-top: 3px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 12px;
    -moz-border-radius: 12px;
    border-radius: 12px;
    background-image: url(images/pdf_icon32.png);
}
```

Comment: Always avoid the iF word

Comment: I want to encourage to avoid directly using the class-attribute. This will overwrite changes made by other plugins on this element.

Answer (score 10):

This solution did the trick for me

```
<a ng-style="{true: {paddingLeft: '25px'}, false: {}}[deleteTriggered]">...</a>
```

Answer (score 9):

You can use ternary expression.  There are two ways to do this:

```
<div ng-style="myVariable > 100 ? {'color': 'red'} : {'color': 'blue'}"></div>
```

or...

```
<div ng-style="{'color': (myVariable > 100) ? 'red' : 'blue' }"></div>
```

Comment: Maybe u will find it better:

<div ng-style="{ 'color': (myVariable > 100)? 'red' : 'blue' }"></div>

Comment: Dudi, if not better, just as useful, so I added it to @maykel's "ternary expression" answer.  Thanks to both of you!

Answer (score 7):

Another option when you need a simple css style of one or two properties:

View:

```
<tr ng-repeat="element in collection">
    [...amazing code...] 
    <td ng-style="{'background-color': getTrColor(element.myvar)}">
        {{ element.myvar }}
    </td>
    [...more amazing code...]
</tr>
```

Controller:

```
$scope.getTrColor = function (colorIndex) {
    switch(colorIndex){
        case 0: return 'red';
        case 1: return 'green';
        default: return 'yellow';
    }
};
```

Answer (score 6):

See the following example

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html ng-app>
    <head>
    <title>Demo Changing CSS Classes Conditionally with Angular</title>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.0.7/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script src="res/js/controllers.js"></script>

    <style>

    .checkboxList {
        border:1px solid #000;
        background-color:#fff;
        color:#000;
        width:300px;
        height: 100px;
        overflow-y: scroll;
    }

    .uncheckedClass {
       background-color:#eeeeee;
       color:black;
    }
    .checkedClass {
        background-color:#3ab44a;
        color:white;
    }
    </style>

    </head>
    <body ng-controller="TeamListCtrl">
    <b>Teams</b>
    <div id="teamCheckboxList" class="checkboxList">

    <div class="uncheckedClass" ng-repeat="team in teams" ng-class="{'checkedClass': team.isChecked, 'uncheckedClass': !team.isChecked}">

    <label>
    <input type="checkbox" ng-model="team.isChecked" />
    <span>{{team.name}}</span>
    </label>
    </div>
    </div>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Answer (score 2):

As of AngularJS v1.2.0rc, `ng-class` and even `ng-attr-class` fail with SVG elements (They did work earlier, even with normal binding inside the class attribute)

Specifically, none of these work now:

```
ng-class="current==this_element?'active':' ' "
ng-attr-class="{{current==this_element?'active':' '}}"
class="class1 class2 .... {{current==this_element?'active':''}}"
```

As a workaround, I've to use

```
ng-attr-otherAttr="{{current==this_element?'active':''}}"
```

and then style using

```
[otherAttr='active'] {
   ... styles ...
}
```

Answer (score 1):

One more (in the future) way to conditionally apply style is by conditionally creating scoped style

```
<style scoped type="text/css" ng-if="...">

</style>
```

But nowadays only FireFox supports scoped styles.

Answer (score 1):

well i would suggest you to check condition in your controller with a function returning **true** or **false** .

```
<div class="week-wrap" ng-class="{today: getTodayForHighLight(todayDate, day.date)}">{{day.date}}</div>
```

and in your controller check the condition

```
$scope.getTodayForHighLight = function(today, date){
    return (today == date);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

There is one more option that I recently discovered that some people may find useful because it allows you to change a CSS rule within a style element - thus avoiding the need for repeated use of an angular directive such as ng-style, ng-class, ng-show, ng-hide, ng-animate, and others.

This option makes use of a service with service variables which are set by a controller and watched by an attribute-directive I call "custom-style".  This strategy could be used in many different ways, and I attempted to provide some general guidance with this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/gavinpalmer1984/ks0o2rte/1/).

```
var app = angular.module('myApp', ['ui.bootstrap']);
app.service('MainService', function(){
    var vm = this;
});
app.controller('MainCtrl', function(MainService){
    var vm = this;
    vm.ms = MainService;
});
app.directive('customStyle', function(MainService){
    return {
        restrict : 'A',
        link : function(scope, element, attr){
            var style = angular.element('<style></style>');
            element.append(style);
            scope.$watch(function(){ return MainService.theme; },
                function(){
                    var css = '';
                    angular.forEach(MainService.theme, function(selector, key){
                        angular.forEach(MainService.theme[key], function(val, k){
                            css += key + ' { '+k+' : '+val+'} ';
                        });                        
                    });
                    style.html(css);
                }, true);
        }
    };
});
```

Answer (score 0):

One thing to watch is - if the CSS style has dashes - you must remove them. So if you want to set `background-color`, the correct way is:

```
ng-style="{backgroundColor:myColor}"
```

Comment: No, you don't have to. ng-style="{'background-color':myColor}" works perfectly well.

Answer (score -1):

Here's how i conditionally applied gray text style on a disabled button

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  styleUrls: [ './app.component.css' ],
  template: `
  <button 
    (click)='buttonClick1()' 
    [disabled] = "btnDisabled"
    [ngStyle]="{'color': (btnDisabled)? 'gray': 'black'}">
    {{btnText}}
  </button>`
})
export class AppComponent  {
  name = 'Angular';
  btnText = 'Click me';
  btnDisabled = false;
  buttonClick1() {
    this.btnDisabled = true;
    this.btnText = 'you clicked me';
    setTimeout(() => {
      this.btnText = 'click me again';
      this.btnDisabled = false
      }, 5000);
  }
}
```

Here's a working example:
https://stackblitz.com/edit/example-conditional-disable-button?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html

Comment: The tag on the question says 'AngularJS', which this is not.