# apply ngClass to element where ngRepeat is declared

Tags: javascript, html, arrays, angularjs

I have a table where rows are generated using AngularJS ngRpeat:

```
<tr ng-repeat="player in division">
  <td>{{player.name}}</td>
  <td>{{player.score}}</td>
</tr>
```

The array looks a bit like this:

```
$scope.divison = [
  {
    name: "John Doe",
    score: "10",
    goingUp : true
  },
  {
    name: "Bob Marley",
    score: "20"
  }
];
```

Now, what if I wanted to apply `ng-class` to the table row based on that particular `ng-repeat`? I would have though this might work:

```
<tr ng-repeat="player in division" ng-class="'goingUp' : player.goingUp">
  <td>{{player.name}}</td>
  <td>{{player.score}}</td>
</tr>
```

Alas this doesn't work. Probably because the ng-class doesn't sit inside that repeat element. How can I get this working though?

Comment: try: `ngclass="(player.goingUp) ? 'goingUp' : ''"`

Comment: ng-class="{'goingUp' : player.goingUp}"

Comment: @Second2None thanks, I was just missing those brackets. If you would like to post that as an answer I will accept it as the correct syntax and easiest method.

Comment: It is a bug.

https://github.com/angular/angular.js/issues/2368

It is unclear if the fix is in the current release version.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Correct syntax is

```
ng-class="{'goingUp' : player.goingUp}"
```

Answer (score 0):

It should be able to do so like in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15410652/using-ng-repeat-and-ng-class-on-rows-inside-a-table) case. You could write a function in to your controllers scope that returns appropriate class:

```
$scope.isGoingUp = function(player)
{
  if (player.goingUp) return "goingUp";
  return "notGoingUp";
}
```

and then call it like this

```
ng-class="isGoingUp(player)"
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Whilst this method may work, simply adding brackets worked for me and was easier.