# Check if item is in list (inside a directive)

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have the following directive which uses two lists: `listGroup` and `listAll`.
They are JSON objects like this:

```
$scope.usersGroup = [
  { id: '1', name: 'User 1' },
  { id: '2', name: 'User 2' },
  { id: '3', name: 'User 3' }
]
```

I want to add a class to each item if `item` is already in `userGroup`:

**JS:**

```
  .directive('tableList', function() {
    return {
      restrict: 'EA',
      template: '<--SOME CODE' + 
        '<tr class="ADD CLASS IF ITEM IS IN LISTGROUP" ng-repeat="item in listAll">' +
          '<th scope="row"><input type="checkbox" value="0" ng-model="item.selected"></th>' + 
          '<td><a href="#/groups/{{item.id}}">{{item.name}}</a></td>
        'MORE CODE-->',
      scope: {
        listName: "@",
        listGroup: "=",
        listAll: "=",
        submit: "&"
      },
      controller: function() {},
      link: function(scope, elem, attr, ctrl) {
        scope.checkAll = function() {
          if (scope.selectedAll) {
            scope.selectedAll = false
          } else {
            scope.selectedAll = true
          }
          angular.forEach(scope.listAll, function(item) {
            item.selected = scope.selectedAll
          })
        }
      }
    };
  })
```

**HTML:**

```
  <table-list
list-name="users"
list-group="usersGroup"
list-all="usersAll"
submit="submit()">
  </table-list
```

What's the AngularJS-way of doing this?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [using ng-repeat and ng-class on rows inside a table](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15410652/using-ng-repeat-and-ng-class-on-rows-inside-a-table)

Comment: Use `ng-class` on `tr` tag

Answer (score 1):

I don't think there is a specific angular way. I would simply set a flag in listAll

```
link: function(scope, elem, attr, ctrl) {
        ...
        var listGroupIds = {};
        angular.forEach(scope.listGroup, function(item) {
          listGroupIds[item.id] = true;
        });
        angular.forEach(scope.listAll, function(item) {
          item.inListGroup = item.id in listGroupIds;
        });
```

Then in the template

```
template: '<--SOME CODE' + 
        '<tr ng-class="{'myClass': item.inListGroup}" ng-repeat="item in listAll">' +
          '<th scope="row"><input type="checkbox" value="0" ng-model="item.selected"></th>' + 
          '<td><a href="#/groups/{{item.id}}">{{item.name}}</a></td>
        'MORE CODE-->',
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I used the `name` property instead, but weird, the class is not being applied: `<tr ng-class="{'myClass': item.inListGroup}" ng-repeat="item in listAll" class="ng-scope">` I copied exactly what there was in your code.

Comment: did you change class to ng-class?

Answer (score 1):

Use [ng-class](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngClass) in `tr` tag:

```
<tr ng-repeat="item in listAll" ng-class="getRowClass(item)">
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't even need to write anything in controller or link function. Just use [Array.prototype.indexOf](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/indexOf) method, super fast and convenient:

```
<tr class="{selected: listGroup.indexOf(item) > -1}" ng-repeat="item in listAll">
```

Important: `listGroup` must contain references to the same objects `listAll` has (which is how it should be anyway).

Comment: that assumes that the same element is contained both in listGroup and listAll, the comparison could be on the id only. Moreover this might not scale with the number of elements, could be worth pointing that out.

Comment: @SimoneZandara Of course, listGroup should have same references. But I believe this is how it should be in 90% of cases. Not, sure what you mean by "not scale" though - scales perfectly.

Comment: it's an O(N^2) approach, i meant this