# Applying style to UI bootstrap header

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-bootstrap

I referenced this post: [Header issues](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19481643/how-to-set-class-style-of-accordion-heading-in-angular-ui)

Has anyone figured out a way using conditional Angular styling to modify UI-boostrap? Neither ng-class, ngClass, ng-style nor any of the other methods mentioned in this post [conditional styling](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13813255/2573069) seem to work.

Hoping to use the Bootstrap UI. Should I use a Bootstrap styler or modify the css directly?

Apologies for the newbie question.