# How to add class to radio button and checkboxes in Angular if checked or selected not on change

Tags: javascript, angularjs, checkbox, radio-button, ng-class

I want to use ngClass conditionlly if the item is checked.  Basically in a way that if the data for the particular model is set and visually the user will see the items selected on either a radio button or check-box that a class will be added to it also allowing me to set different css for checked/selected items.  I am using http://vitalets.github.io/checklist-model/ to set up check-boxes and just a regular ngRepeat for radio buttons.  In the exaple of the check-box model they show the user item from the set of check boxes selected already.  I want the user to load the page and have the item selected already but also with a class added to just the items selected.  I do not want to be dependent on a 'change' function because that requires an action from the user.  I want it bound to the page or with in ngClass.

I have looked into [How do I conditionally apply CSS styles in AngularJS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13813254/how-do-i-conditionally-apply-css-styles-in-angularjs)
but it did not seem to help with my situation.

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 3):

You can apply a class conditionally like so:

```
<div ng-repeat="animal in animals">
    <input type="checkbox" ng-model="animal.isHungry" ng-class="{'when-condition-true': animal.isHungry}">
</div>
```

The class `when-condition-true` will be applied when the `isHungry` attribute of the current `animal` is truthy in the controller.

Alternatively can also switch a class conditionally like so:

```
<div ng-repeat="animal in animals">
    <input type="checkbox" ng-model="animal.isHungry" ng-class="animal.isHungry ? 'when-condition-true' : 'when-condition-false'">
</div>
```

Both of these will work on page load and don't need interaction from your users. But when they do check and uncheck your classes will be added or removed automatically.