# What is the difference between ng-class and ng-style?

Tags: css, angularjs, angularjs-directive

`ng-class` and `ng-style` both seem to be methods of dynamically setting CSS classes. What is the difference between them?

Comment: [`ng-class`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngClass) sets classes. [`ng-style`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngStyle) sets styles. [This answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13813254/how-do-i-conditionally-apply-css-styles-in-angularjs#13813255) might be informative.

Answer (score 38, accepted):

[ng-style](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngStyle) is used to interpolate javascript object into **style** attribute, not css class.

Following directive will be translated to *style="color:red"*

```
ng-style="{color: 'red'}"
```

And [ng-class](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngClass) directive translates your object into **class** attribute.

Following will be translated to *class="deleted"* when **isDeleted** variable is *true*.

```
ng-class="{'deleted': isDeleted}"
```

### Note:

There is one more use case for ng-style. If you want to interpolate something in style attribute, you should consider using ng-style. Otherwise, that would not work before Internet Explorer 11 as [documentation](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/ie) suggests.

So, instead of using style:

```
style="width: {{progress}}"
```

Use ng-style:

```
ng-style="{'width':progress}"
```

Answer (score 6):

In `ng-class` you are loading a CSS class defined in some place, like Bootstrap. In `ng-style` you are setting the CSS style that you want that element has, example:

```
ng-style="{ 'background-color': person.email == selectedPerson.email ? 'lightgray' : ' '}" //background-color is a style
```

`has-error` is a class defined in somewhere that is composed by style(s):

```
ng-class="{ 'has-error’: !theForm.email.$valid, 'has-success':theForm.email.$valid}
```

Answer (score 1):

From the official Docs: https://angular.io/api/common/NgClass

1. **These are different ways to use ngClass**

   ...

   ```
   <some-element [ngClass]="['first', 'second']">...</some-element>

   <some-element [ngClass]="{'first': true, 'second': true, 'third': false}">...</some-
   ```

   element>

   ```
   <some-element [ngClass]="stringExp|arrayExp|objExp">...</some-element>

   <some-element [ngClass]="{'class1 class2 class3' : true}">...</some-element>
   ```

**2. Similarly with ngStyle you can do the following:**

```
**< some-element [ngStyle]="{'font-style': styleExp}">...</some-element>**
```

- Your styleExp can be anything that evaluates to a legal value for the attribute you are setting ,e.g. font-size in the example above
- Alternatively,

  ****< some-element [ngStyle]="objExp">...****
- Where objExp is an object containing key-value pairs of your style attributes
  e.g. { width: 40, margin: '2em' } etc.

Answer (score 1):

**ngClass**

ngClass attribute directive helps to add and remove CSS class names conditionally.

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  template: `
    <h1 [ngClass]="[isActive ? 'my-color' : 'red-color']">Hello angular</h1>
    <button (click)="changeColor()">Change color</button>
  `,
  styles: [
    `
      .my-color {
        background-color: aqua;
      }

      .red-color {
        background-color: red;
      }
    `,
  ],
})
export class AppComponent {
  isActive = false;

  changeColor() {
    this.isActive = !this.isActive;
  }
}
```

**ngStyle**

ngStyle attribute directive helps us to add and remove inline styles dynamically.

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  template: `
    <h1 [ngStyle]="{ backgroundColor: h1color }">Hello angular</h1>
    <button (click)="changeColor()">Change color</button>
  `,
})
export class AppComponent {
  h1color = 'red';

  changeColor() {
    this.h1color = 'green';
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Theoretically they both are different, but practically at some point they both become same

**ngStyle** is used to add style dynamically at run time and

**ngClass** is used to add some class dynamically at run time but class also holds some css content, so indirectly you are also adding css here dynamically