# How angular defines css

Tags: javascript, html, css, angularjs

Angular defines some css classes like ng-hide and more. How and where it does it? in angular.js I've a possible definition:

````
 * ### Overriding .ng-hide
 *
 * By default, the `.ng-hide` class will style the element with `display:none!important`. If you wish to change
 * the hide behavior with ngShow/ngHide then this can be achieved by restating the styles for the `.ng-hide`
 * class in CSS:
 *
 * ```css
 * .ng-hide {
 *   /&#42; this is just another form of hiding an element &#42;/
 *   display:block!important;
 *   position:absolute;
 *   top:-9999px;
 *   left:-9999px;
 * }
 * ```
````

If it's really the definition, what's that ```css syntax? Found nothing about it.

Comment: I think the following question could help you 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13813254/how-do-i-conditionally-apply-css-styles-in-angularjs

Comment: Where are you pulling this definition from?

Comment: You can disable this behavior in production setting the  `$compileProvider.debugInfoEnabled`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're looking at comments which are meant to be used as documentation, not the actual code.

If you scroll right to the bottom of the `angular.js` file, you'll see a line beginning with:

```
!angular.$$csp() && angular.element(document).find('head').prepend('<style type="text/css">@charset "UTF-8";[ng\\:cloak],[ng-cloak],[data-ng-cloak],[x-ng-cloak],.ng-cloak,.x-ng-cloak,.ng-hide{display:none !important;}ng\\:form{display:block;}</style>');
```

That's where the actual CSS is defined. There's not that much of it, and it's pretty much just limited to hiding things like this.

Answer (score 1):

> Angular defines some css classes like ng-hide and more.

No, it doesn't. Those are **HTML classes**.

There is no such thing as a CSS class. CSS has class **selectors** which allow you to apply styles to elements based on which HTML classes they are members of.

Angular uses HTML classes primarily to select elements with JavaScript, not CSS.

The few areas where it does use CSS can be found in [the CSS directory](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/tree/master/css) of the source tree.

---

> what's that ```css syntax?

That isn't CSS. It is markdown. It means "This is a block of code". You are looking at the source code to documentation. It will be parsed by markdown (and, presumably, a tool like JSDoc) and converted into HTML.