# Table row colour according to result

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

I am new to AngularJs I am getting json data which is in format:

```
[
  {
    'StudentName':'abc',
    'maths':'0',
    'english':'0',
    'economics':'0',
  }
]
```

I want to calculate each students marks and if marks is less than 40% then table row should be red else else should be green.
I have tried.
HTML

```
<div ng-app="MyApp" ng-controller="con1"> 
  <table id="table1">
    <tr>
      <th>student Name</th>
      <th>History Marks</th>
      <th>Maths Marks</th>
      <th>Economics Marks</th>
      <th>Percentage</th>
    </tr>
    <tr ng-repeat="x in data" ng-if="{{co(per(x))}}" ng-class="pass">
      <td>{{x.StudentName}}</td>
      <td>{{x.maths}}</td>
      <td>{{x.economics}}</td>
      <td>{{x.english}}</td>
      <td>{{per(x)}}%</td>
    </tr>
  </table>
```

Script

```
var app = angular.module('MyApp', []);
app.controller('con1', function ($scope, $http) {
    $http.get('/ajax/data').success(function (res) { $scope.data = res; });
    $scope.per = function (x) {
        avg = ((parseInt(x.maths) + parseInt(x.economics) + parseInt(x.english)) * 100) / 300;
        return avg;
    };
    $scope.co = function (x) { (x > 40) ? k = 1 : k = 0; return (k); }
});
```

css

```
.pass{background:green;}
.fail{background:red;}
```

I am getting percentage but according to percentage I am not getting the row colour.

Comment: when new to angularjs it is very good to not use ANY jQuery

Comment: I actually don't see where jQuery is being used.

Comment: I think a lot of people confuse jQuery with Javascript.

Comment: Can't Jquery and AngularJS co exist? :) 
Haven't started using Angular but I'm using Jquery

Comment: @JaredT, Yes, however, you will run into a lot of Angular purists that say you should NEVER use jQuery and Angular together.  I disagree.  In theory it's a great concept.  In reality, it just makes some things way easier to use jQuery.

Comment: @Scottie Some of the "official" AngularJS plugins on GitHub are just wrappers for jQuery plugins, though (e.g. [Angular-DragDrop](https://github.com/codef0rmer/angular-dragdrop))

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You need [ngClass](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngClass)

> The ngClass directive allows you to dynamically set CSS classes on an HTML element by databinding an expression that represents all classes to be added.

*Code*

```
ng-class='{ "pass" : co(per(x)) == 1, "fail" : co(per(x)) == 0 }'
```

*OR*, From @RevanProdigalKnight comment

```
ng-class="co(per(x)) ? 'pass' : 'fail'"
```

---

when calling function with `ngIf`, You don;t need string interpolation.

*Use*

```
ng-if="co(per(x))"
```

*instead of*

```
ng-if="{{co(per(x))}}"
```

Comment: and if anything, if you want to change classes depending on a value.... you should be using ng-class. . .

Comment: You could also have `ng-class="co(per(x)) ? 'pass' : 'fail'"`

Comment: @RevanProdigalKnight I learned something new today!  I didn't know you could use ternary operators in ng-class.  Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

Use `ng-class`

```
ng-class="{pass: per(x) >= 40, fail: per(x) < 40}"
```

References:

1. [How do I conditionally apply CSS styles in AngularJS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13813254/how-do-i-conditionally-apply-css-styles-in-angularjs)
2. [What is the best way to conditionally apply a class?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7792652/what-is-the-best-way-to-conditionally-apply-a-class)

Comment: Minor fix... The classes should be pass and fail, not green and red.

Answer (score 1):

ng-if will actually remove the row from the DOM if it's below 40%.

You'll want

```
<tr ng-repeat="x in data" ng-class="{ 'pass' : per(x) > 40 }">
```

As a side note, it's recommended not to use functions in ng-repeats because performance can suffer significantly.