# How to add inline css in angular in different view with same content but different style?

Tags: html, css, angularjs, angularjs-scope, angularjs-ng-repeat

Here my html-

```
     <p  ng-if= "editMode=='edit'" style="margin-left: 1px;margin-top: -2px;">===some messages---</p>
     <p  ng-if= "editMode=='addNew'" style="margin-left: 1px;margin-top: -2px;">===some messages---</p>
```

In above example i have two diffrent view "edit" and "addNew" with same content but style is different. How to do that?

Comment: i just tried using ng-if .. But code won;t look good.. any other suggestion?

Comment: please provide your full html with your controller

Comment: Use `ng-style`. Based on the expression evaluation the style is determined.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `ng-class`:

```
<p ng-class='{"class1": editMode=="edit", "class2": editMode=="addNew"}'>===some messages---</p>
```

And in css file:

```
.class1 {
     /* some styles */
}
.class2 {
     /* some styles */
}
```

However there are many more built in directives in AngularJS that you can use. For a more detailed explanation about the options available and with examples, take a look at the [accepted answer for a similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13813254/how-do-i-conditionally-apply-css-styles-in-angularjs#answer-13813255)

Comment: But if i want to add it in inline itself?  is there anyway?

Comment: @saurav You can use `ng-style` for inline style.