# AngularJS + CSS: best practice for a live preview?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, angularjs

I've a **textfield** with a hex-color as it's value. I'd like to display the impact **live**, e.g. by changing the body's **background-color**.

The [code](https://jsfiddle.net/uL8b5ack/) works but feels wrong/dirty. I'd like to avoid jQuery's `.css()` and follow the angular principles.

```
<div data-ng-app>    
    <span data-ng-init="colors.bg='#00FF00';"/>

    <style type="text/css">
    body {
        background: {{colors.bg}}; <!-- dirty ?! -->
    }
    </style>

    <input type="text" data-ng-model="colors.bg"/> 
</div>
```

Does anyone know a good/clean solution?  Thanks in advance!

Comment: This might help http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13813254/how-do-i-conditionally-apply-css-styles-in-angularjs  hint use : ng-style

Comment: You could use a change event on your input and use an ng-style on your body tag?

Comment: @SvenB Please post it as an answer and I'll accept it. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use a change event on your input and use an ng-style on your body tag