# Change the background color of a div in angular

Tags: angularjs, background-color, angularjs-ng-click

I would like to change the bg colour of div when clicked on that particular div.
The div is placed in a slider panel. For example, if I click Home, the slider gets hidden and the home panel opens up. Again when I open the slider, the bg colour should be retained to say that I am in Home panel. I tried using ng-style and ng-class, but it doesnt work.

```html
<div class="menu-grid-con all-icons">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col col-50 text-center" ng-click="menu.onHomeButtonClick()">
      <img src="images/iconHome.png" class="menu-icons">
      <br> <!-- TODO: to change -->
      <p translate="MENU_HOME" class="menu-icon-text"></p>
    </div>
    <div 
      class="col col-50 text-center" 
      ng-click="menu.onFlyerButtonClick()" 
      ng-style={"background-color:blue;} "
    >
      <img src="images/iconWeeklyFlyer.png" class="menu-weekly-flyer-icons">
      <br> <!-- TODO: to change -->
      <p translate="MENU_WEEKLY" class="menu-icon-text"></p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Can you provide **fiddle**  with what you tried

Comment: I tried to add ng-class as well.
     <div class="col col-50 text-center" ng-click="menu.onFlyerButtonClick()" ng-class="background-color:grey;">
But bg colour is not reflecting in the div.

Answer (score 0):

Your `ng-style` syntax is wrong.

It should be

```
ng-style="{'background-color':'blue'}"
```

Please, note that `ng-class` take a css `class` not individual properties

```
<div ng-class="bgColor"></div>
```

CSS

```
.bgColor{
  background-color:blue;
}
```

There are many different ways to declare `ng-class`. Take a look [here](https://scotch.io/tutorials/the-many-ways-to-use-ngclass).

This useful SO [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13813254/how-do-i-conditionally-apply-css-styles-in-angularjs) talks about different ways to conditionally applying css in AngularJS.

Answer (score 0):

```
ng-style="{'background-color':'#CCCCCC'}">
```

[Reference](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngStyle)