# Apply color code from AngularJS file to sass

Tags: javascript, css, angularjs, sass

Based on login I'll get the color code and I'm storing it in `localstorage` and getting it throughout application. But challenging thing is I've to replace the color code in sass file.

```
$Primary-color:#491e6a;
$Secondary-color:#e5673a;
$button-color:#eb0e4d;
$Black:#000;
$White:#fff;
```

Here the color code I get on login have to replace for `$Primary-color`
for example if I get `#ecaa0b` I have to replace it with that old color and will apply to all css files.

Comment: Use js on frontend to change color. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13813254/how-do-i-conditionally-apply-css-styles-in-angularjs

Comment: You cannot. Change it in css inline or using any class or use js for color

Comment: I doubt it's possible. Even if you've somehow changed those color values with angular, you will need to compile the sass file to CSS for the colors to appear.

Comment: I have got this by using  ng-style="{color: myColor}"

Answer (score 0):

```
$rootScope.schoolColor = localStorage.getItem("schoolColor");
```

and in html

```
<div  ng-style="{background: schoolColor}">
                        <h3>Latest Events</h3>
                    </div>
```