# Create page with complete separate CSS in Angular

Tags: javascript, html, css, angularjs, single-page-application

I want to create a login page for an **AngularJS** project. Is there a way that I can make this login page as independent as possible, especially for CSS. Basically, I want to implement a separate CSS for this specific login page without inherit any style from master page.

As this login page part of this SPA angular application, is this possible?

Comment: don't link any stylesheets to the login page?

Answer (score 0):

You could just remove the `link` element - and keep a reference to put it back in place if need be.

```
var css = document.querySelector('link[href~="bootstrap.css"]'); 
document.removeChild(css);
```

Or you can conditionally apply css styles as answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13813255/1405376):

> - **[ng-class](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.directive:ngClass)** - use when the set of CSS styles is static/known ahead of time
> - **[ng-style](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.directive:ngStyle)** - use when you can't define a CSS class because the style values may change dynamically.  Think programmable control
>     of the style values.
> - **[ng-show](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.directive:ngShow)** and **[ng-hide](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.directive:ngHide)** - use if you only need to show or hide something (modifies CSS)
> - **[ng-if](http://code.angularjs.org/1.1.5/docs/api/ng.directive:ngIf)** - new in version 1.1.5, use instead of the more verbose ng-switch if you only need to check for a single condition
>     (modifies DOM)
> - **[ng-switch](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.directive:ngSwitch)** - use instead of using several mutually exclusive ng-shows (modifies DOM)
> - **[ng-disabled](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.directive:ngDisabled)** and **[ng-readonly](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.directive:ngReadonly)** - use to restrict form element behavior
> - **[ng-animate](http://code.angularjs.org/1.1.4/docs/api/ng.directive:ngAnimate)** - new in version 1.1.4, use to add CSS3 transitions/animations

Answer (score 0):

If you are using ui-router, you can use diferent master views for every view that you want.

```
      .state('masterLogin', {
                  abstract: true,
                  url: "/master",
                  templateUrl: "/app/Commons/views/masterlogin.html",
              })

     .state('masterLogin.login', {
                  url: "/login",
                  templateUrl: "/app/Modules/views/login.html",
                  data: { pageTitle: 'Forbidden' }
              })

     .state('anotherMaster', {
                  abstract: true,
                  url: "/anothermaster",
                  templateUrl: "/app/Commons/views/anotherMaster.html",
              })

     .state('anotherMaster.Home', {
                  url: "/Home",
                  templateUrl: "/app/Modules/views/home.html",
                  data: { pageTitle: 'Home' }
              })
```