# css - Setting the background of an input element as a combination of three colors

Tags: html, css

I know that there is a solution based on the use of images, but I would still like to explore other alternatives.

Imagine you have a numeric input element that can accept any value, but legal values are confined between MIN and MAX.

Now, the background of the element should reflect the validity of the entered value. For instance:

*Legal Value*:

```
  +---------------------------------+
  |                                 |
  |                                 |
  |      [green background]         |
  |                                 |
  |                                 |
  +---------------------------------+
```

*Above Max*:

```
  +---------------------------------+
  |                                 |
  |       [red background]          |
  |                                 |
  |------- [black line] ------------|
  |      [green background]         |
  +---------------------------------+
```

*Below Min*:

```
  +---------------------------------+
  |      [green background]         |
  |------- [black line] ------------|
  |                                 |
  |       [red background]          |
  |                                 |
  +---------------------------------+
```

One additional option would be not to use three colors but gradients with color switch at different highs within the element.

Is this possible at all using **css**?

Thanks.

**EDIT**:

Though the answer posted by Paige Meinke does basically work, it looks that either I'm doing something wrong or it does now work when combined with AngularJS.

When MIN/MAX values for a numeric element are set, AngularJS automatically adds the classes `ng-invalid-min` or `ng-invalid-max` when the entered value exceeds the pre-defined MAX/MIN.

So, I added the following piece to the page:

```
    <style>
        .ng-invalid-min {
        background: #ff3232; /* Old browsers */
        background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #ff3232 45%, #ff3232 45%, #000000 50%, #80ed94 50%); /* FF3.6-15 */
        background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #ff3232 45%,#ff3232 45%,#000000 50%,#80ed94 50%); /* Chrome10-25,Safari5.1-6 */
        background: linear-gradient(to bottom, #ff3232 45%,#ff3232 45%,#000000 50%,#80ed94 50%); /* W3C, IE10+, FF16+, Chrome26+, Opera12+, Safari7+ */
        }
    </style>
```

and still, when a value below the minimum is entered, no color changes take place.

Am I doing something wrong or the combination with AngularJS/Bootstrap creates conflicts in this particular case?

Thanks again.

**EDIT 2**

Using the great suggestion posted by Paige (see below), I finally got it working the way I wanted. Here is the css + html that do the job:

```
    <style>
        .ng-invalid-max {
            background: #ff3232; /* Old browsers */
            background: -moz-linear-gradient   (      top, #ff3232 80%,#ff3232 80%,#000000 80%,#80ed94 20%); /* FF3.6-15 */
            background: -webkit-linear-gradient(      top, #ff3232 80%,#ff3232 80%,#000000 80%,#80ed94 20%); /* Chrome10-25,Safari5.1-6 */
            background: linear-gradient        (to bottom, #ff3232 80%,#ff3232 80%,#000000 80%,#80ed94 20%); /* W3C, IE10+, FF16+, Chrome26+, Opera12+, Safari7+ */
            color: white ;
        }            
        .ng-invalid-min {
            background: #ff3232; /* Old browsers */
            background: -moz-linear-gradient   (      top, #80ed94 20%,#80ed94 20%,#000000 20%,#ff3232 20%); /* FF3.6-15 */
            background: -webkit-linear-gradient(      top, #80ed94 20%,#80ed94 20%,#000000 20%,#ff3232 20%); /* Chrome10-25,Safari5.1-6 */
            background: linear-gradient        (to bottom, #80ed94 20%,#80ed94 20%,#000000 20%,#ff3232 20%); /* W3C, IE10+, FF16+, Chrome26+, Opera12+, Safari7+ */
            color: white ;
        }            


    </style>

        <input type="number" 
               ng-model="Test_Number" 
               id="Test_Number" 
               name="Test_Number" 
               min="10" 
               max="100"
               style="position:relative;margin:30px">
```

Many thank to Paige for *showing me the light!!!!*

Comment: I think you'd need to add some JavaScript to the mix in order to achieve the change in color depending on the input value. But then it would be easy thanks to gradients.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would use gradients, colorzilla.com is a great gradient creator. You can drag the nodes to be closer together to make it look like a solid black line in the middle instead of a gradient.

```css
/* Permalink - use to edit and share this gradient: http://colorzilla.com/gradient-editor/#ff3232+45,ff3232+45,000000+50,80ed94+50 */
input{
background: #ff3232; /* Old browsers */
background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #ff3232 45%, #ff3232 45%, #000000 50%, #80ed94 50%); /* FF3.6-15 */
background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #ff3232 45%,#ff3232 45%,#000000 50%,#80ed94 50%); /* Chrome10-25,Safari5.1-6 */
background: linear-gradient(to bottom, #ff3232 45%,#ff3232 45%,#000000 50%,#80ed94 50%); /* W3C, IE10+, FF16+, Chrome26+, Opera12+, Safari7+ */
filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr='#ff3232', endColorstr='#80ed94',GradientType=0 ); /* IE6-9 */
}
```

```html
<input type="number">
```

Comment: Paige, could you take a look at the EDIT I made to my question. I'm not getting what I want (though your suggestion DOES work in a basic scenario).

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13813254/how-do-i-conditionally-apply-css-styles-in-angularjs   Could you use ng-class?    https://www.w3schools.com/angular/ng_ng-class.asp   Based on the value of the input, apply the class?

Comment: Thank you Paige. I'll try this approach and let you know.

Comment: Hello Paige, see **EDIT 2** with a description of a working solution.

Comment: Awesome, I'm very glad it worked. You were definitely heading in the right direction originally.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the code of the CSS:

```
.two-colour-background {
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, yellow, yellow 30%, white 30%, white);
    border: solid 10px #000;
}
```

You can use here to manipulate the CSS: http://jsfiddle.net/UES6U/2/