# Angularjs - How can it point to all the ng-repeat from on of them by a ng-click?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

What can I do to point to the other ng-repeat elements from the ng-click function?
I would like to modify the {{nameClass}} of the other ng-repeat elements from a click to someone of them.

Html:

```
<li class="{{nameclass}}" ng-repeat="person in people" ng-click="somefunction()"></li>
```

javascript:

```
function somefunction(){
     this.nameclass = "some";
     //what to set the other classes???
}
```

Comment: You need to be more specific. Explain a little better.

Comment: That's all there... I would like to modify the {{nameClass}} of the other ng-repeat elements from a click to someone of them.

Comment: So you want all the items to have `some` class name after you click one of them?

Comment: Yes some class value.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can pass in the class you want to set into the function on ng-click.see this plunk http://plnkr.co/edit/oXavr7CVTpPfPUZJO0f9?p=preview

Answer (score 1):

You could also utilize [ng-class](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngClass) and have that set some boolean to enable a given class on whatever objects you want.

In your controller

```
$scope.someFunction = function (){
    $scope.active = true;
}
$scope.someOtherFunction = function (){
    $scope.loading = true;
}
```

In your HTML

```
<li ng-class="{activeClass: active, someOtherClass: loading}" ng-repeat="person in people" ng-click="somefunction()"></li>
```

What this does is add "activeClass" to the class definition when "active" is true. I added a second one "someOtherClass" to further illustrate this example.

Answer (score 0):

If your goal is to set the *same* class value to all the items then you should use $scope.nameclass:

```
function somefunction(){
    $scope.nameclass = "some";
}
```

And the different is that when you use `this.nameclass` you set `nameclass` property of the current item scope, not the parent scope *all* items belong to. When you set it to `$scope` object then all the LI items inherit `nameclass` not only clicked one.

Comment: Yes I know, but if I wanted to set all the class at some value, and after the class of the "this" ng-repeat element.. The next time when I gonna click to another ng-repeat element, the class of element before keep its old value.

Comment: I created a Plunker for you: http://plnkr.co/edit/lzribQXc9E5w6LDTFDwB?p=preview
the class some has red text: .some { color: red;}
when you click an item all turn red. Feel free to modify the example.

Hopefully this would help us understand better what you need.

Answer (score 0):

I believe this is what you're looking for:

```
<li ng-class="{true: 'someOther'}[$index!=selectedIndex]" 
    ng-repeat="person in people" ng-click="somefunction($index)">{{person}}</li>

$scope.people = ['Peter','Paul','Mary'];
$scope.selectedIndex = 0;
$scope.somefunction = function(index) {
  $scope.selectedIndex=index;
};
```

In Plunker:

http://plnkr.co/edit/2IsD2W3YclUe0Bc5Q93a?

1. When you click on an item, the index of this item is set as the selectedIndex property on the scope.
2. All items which index *does not equal* this selectedIndex gets the class 'someOther' applied to it.

Full explanation of the expression in ng-class:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/18126926/2331058

Comment: no repeat elements, indipendent elements, it allow you to select both as well.