# Bind an AngularJS directive to a mapping of an array

Tags: angularjs

I have a directive that takes an array of objects. When declaring the directive in markup, the scope has an array of objects that wrap the ones needed by the directive. So I need to apply a map function on the array. What's the right way to do this so updates made to the original array are reflected inside the directive?

Here's a Plunker with a naive approach (which I was surprised to see mostly "work" except for lots of $digest errors): http://plnkr.co/edit/GUCZ3c

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should avoid calling a function from an Angular expression unless, among other things, that function does some very lightweight work (a quick computation, for instance). This [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17497630/is-it-very-bad-to-call-a-function-that-locally-computes-a-value-from-an-angularj) has more details on that matter.

In your case, you should cache the name list and bind it to the directive. Here's an example:

```
app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope) {  
    $scope.people = [
        { name: 'Alice'}, 
        { name: 'Bob' },
        { name: 'Chuck' }
    ];

    $scope.addName = function(name) {
        $scope.people.push({name: name});
    };

    $scope.$watch(function() { return $scope.people.length; }, function() {
        $scope.names = $scope.people.map(function(p) { return p.name; });
    });
});
```

Your directive code remains the same. Here's a [fork](http://plnkr.co/edit/I007Gp?p=preview) of your Plunker.

**Update**: I've changed the code so it uses a `$watch` to update the name list automatically, following @KrisBraun advice.

Comment: Good point about caching. Using a $watch on the underlying array to update the cache would make it cleaner, too, and handle changes outside that controller.

Comment: You're right about using a `$watch` to update the cache automatically.  I'll update the post to use it.

Comment: Nice idea using $scope.people.length for the $watch which will be more space and speed efficient than the whole array. There is a risk other code might add and remove elements yielding a different list with the same length, but knowing my current code that shouldn't be an issue for me.

Answer (score 1):

I believe you need to treat expressions a little differently when binding them to your isolated scope. [Here is a forked plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/QbYHpo?p=preview).

```
app.directive('myDirective', function($compile) {
  return {
    restrict: 'E',
    scope: {
      names: '&namesFunc'
    },
    template: '<div><p>JSON: {{names() | json}}</p><p>Names:</p><ul><li ng-repeat="name in names()">{{name}}</li></ul></div>',
    replace: true,
    link: function(scope, elem, attr, ctrl) {
    }
  };
});
```

Comment: Ah, I should have tried that. For some reason I had thought & bindings weren't updated automatically, but clearly they are.

Comment: Any idea if there are efficiency differences between the two binding methods?

Comment: `&` bindings are not updated. They just provide a way to execute an expression in the context of the parent scope. In this case, the directive is calling `getName()` defined in the parent scope.

Comment: Here is some information on when expressions can cause performance/integrity issues. http://thenittygritty.co/angularjs-pitfalls-using-scopes Read "Pitfall #1: Scope digester and expressions"

Comment: That article has good insights, but I disagree with 'DO NOT use functions in expressions". Instead, it should've said "DO NOT use functions that aren't lightweight in expressions". I asked a [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17497630) precisely on how bad is to call functions in Angular expressions a while ago, and I got one answer that pretty much sums it up, IMO.

Comment: @Michael Benford I concur.