# creating AngularJS directive like ngModel for array

Tags: javascript, arrays, angularjs

Here's my problem: I have a control which I would like to use in AngularJS as an attribute directive (actually I have more but lets just stick with one for now), like the model directive. I have seen a few examples in the documentation and tried to write my directive like that.

For example:

```
<input type="text" my-datepicker ng-model="appointment" />
```

This works fine, but the problem occures when I try this to work with array types.
I debugged to see what is causing the problem, and also searched the documentation after this kind of problems.

Here's how I tried first:

```
.directive('myAnything', function(){
return {
    restrict: 'A',
    require: '?ngModel', // get a hold of NgModelController
    link: function (scope, element, attrs, ngModel) {
        if (!ngModel) return; // do nothing if no ng-model

        // initialize my control on the element
        // ...

        // Specify how UI should be updated
        ngModel.$render = render;

        // Listen for change events to enable binding
        element.on('change', function () {
            scope.$apply(read);
        });
        read();

        function read() {
            // read from controll, write to model
            // ngModel.$setViewValue([{text:'test'},{text:'test2'},{text:'test3'}]);
        }
        function render() {
            if (ngModel.$modelValue) {
                // update controller form model - render
                // ...
            }
        }
    }
};
});
```

Since I am new to AngularJS I am not sure if my understanding is correct. What I came up with so far is that when angular is checking for changes it doesn't make a deep check for the array and so my render function doesn't get called.
Here's a fiddle to demonstrate this: [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/andras_zee/XdjF3/)

I did not find anything about how to tell angular to deep check my model, so I looked deeper in the source at how is it done with the ngModelController, and I thought if I make a base controller like the ngModelController just with the deepcheck it's going to work.

I succeeded to make the myModelController, just like the ngModelController only that the $watch call is made by me passing the third argument true to deep check.

```
$scope.$watch(function myModelWatch() {
                var value = ngModelGet($scope);
                if (!angular.equals(ctrl.$modelValue, value)) {
                    ctrl.$modelValue = value;
                    ctrl.$render();
                }
                return ctrl.$modelValue;
            },
                function (newValue, oldValue) {
                    if (!angular.equals(newValue, oldValue)) {
                        ctrl.$render();
                    }
                },
                true
             );
```

This worked and was even better than the first solution because I could use it without the ngModel directive like this (also more elegant):

```
<input type="text" my-anything="listofappointments" />
```

Again this worked until I applied that directive to another input after which both of them were bound to the last model property.

```
<input type="text" my-anything="secondList" />
```

I debugged this also to the point where I found out that the setter of the directive which is called in angular has an argument (ident) which is set to secondList (the last model property I have on the page).

My question is, what are my options here? Maybe I did not notice in the documentation how this can be done? This looks like an easy scenario... Or maybe I need a deeper understanding of how this is accomplished in angular? Was my approach even good to this problem?

I would appreciate any comment or suggestion! If the second approach is doable I would like to stick with it, because it is obviously more elegant and user friendly (without the ng-model), but if not, the other one would be good as well.

By the way I am using the angular v1.0.8 which is apparently the stable version. (but I don't insist on that either)

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I have a couple suggestions for you here. First, I think you're on the right track by avoiding ngModel. You can take it a step further though, if you use your directive as the element and then specify your array using an attribute. I suspected this would have come up on SO before, and I believe [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18243811/316621) will be useful to you. There's a [Plunker example](http://plnkr.co/edit/I007Gp?p=preview) included that demonstrates the concept of working with an array succinctly.

The last issue you described is pretty common in AngularJS. It occurs when you try to re-use a directive without isolating its scope. The AngularJS [directive guide](http://docs.angularjs.org/guide/directive) explains the concept pretty well in the "Isolating the scope of a directive" section. The Plunker snippet I linked to above does isolate the scope with this piece of the directive definition:

```
    scope: {
      names: '='
    }
```

That is shorthand for this equivalent code:

```
    scope: {
      names: '=names'
    }
```

Which means: "set up an isolate scope, where the *names* variable is bound to the *names* attribute of my directive's element."

That way, each instance of your directive has its own scope and you won't experience the clashes you saw in your tests.

Comment: Thanks for tips, but I would like to avoid having custom elements, because my components need to be initialized on either an input/select/div/etc... It is a possible choice to go on this route but if I could make it like an attribute it would be better. 
I also tried to isolate the scope for this component, but it did not work. With the '=' shorthand the scope would not update. It didn't updated the other component either but neither did this.