# Computed array in Angularjs

Tags: angularjs, directive

I'm implementing an angular directive that is responsible for expanding and collapsing a set of blocks on the page. This directive expects as a parameter a set of "expandable items", all of which should have property `isExpanded`.

```
<expand-collapse-all expandable-items="expandableItems"></expand-collapse-all>
```

The blocks that should expand and collapse look like this:

```
<ul>
    <li ng-repeat="group in groups">
        <block items="group.items" library="group.library"></block>
    </li>
</ul>
```

`expandableItems` array is formed like this:

```
_.forEach(groups, group => {
     expandableItems.push(group.library);
});
```

The problem is that my `expandableItems` should be "computed" array, because `isExpanded` is a property of library, not a group, and groups can be added or deleted, and I don't want to manually update `expandableItems` array each time some group is added or removed.

I see that my problem can be solved by making group object expandable (adding `isExpanded` property to it) and passing entire group to block directive instead of passing items and library separately. But I'm still curious how it can be solved when it is like it is now.

I'm more aquainted with knockoutjs, and I know that in knockoutjs it could be easily achieved by defining `expandableItems` as `ko.computed`. I cannot figure out though how I can do similar thing in angularjs. Can I pass a function somehow to `expand-collapse-all`, that will be recalculating the `expandableItems` array?

I've tried doing this:

```
<expand-collapse-all expandable-items="getExpandableItems(groups)"></expand-collapse-all>
```

, defining `getExpandableItems(groups)` in the constructor of page's controller, but I get error *"Error: 10 $digest() iterations reached. Aborting!"*

Comment: Just found a similar question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18242816/bind-an-angularjs-directive-to-a-mapping-of-an-array

Answer (score 1):

You need to cache the computed array. You cannot return a new array instance each time, since Angular is checking reference equality and a failed check results in a new digest loop.