# Angular JS - Get bigger from Repeat

Tags: javascript, html, loops, angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

I have a list with elements,

```
<li ng-repeat="loan in loans | orderBy:order:reverse" > 
{{ loan.username }}
{{ loan.days }}
```

My question is, can I add a special html tag to the biggest number in loan.days ?

Thank in advance.

Comment: So are you saying that which every iteration's loan.days amount is highest you want to add specific tags?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It would probably be a better idea to add a class to the biggest element:

```
<li ng-repeat="loan in loans | orderBy:order:reverse" ng-class="{ 'biggest': biggest(loan) }>
```

You will then need a function in your controller called `biggest` that takes a single "loan" as it's argument and returns `true` if it's the largest value in the list. You can sort out that logic.

Comment: It's worth mentioning that the `biggest()` function should be very "light" (in computational terms) since it'll be called at every digest cycle. [This question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17497630/is-it-very-bad-to-call-a-function-that-locally-computes-a-value-from-an-angularj) has some good insights on that matter.