# How can I change information in another view via an AngularJS Directive?

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope

Okay, this is a convoluted question and I may be asking for a bad approach. If that's the case, please do let me know.

So I have a `directive` for a navigation bar. When someone clicks something, I managed to get the directive to add a class and therefore load the bar. [Thanks to StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19009352/239879).

But now, I have a service that gets and sets values. When a value is changed in the service, I want to reflect that in a view. Is such a thing possible?

**EDIT**
For clarification, if I do use a `$apply(function()....`, how exactly do I do that? My view has something like. My view is not bound to any particular controller, or scope. Not sure if it should be. But here's a snippet of my view:

```
    <p>
        Are you sure you change that song,
        <br />
  {{ songs[0].title }}
    </p>
```

Here's my directive:

```
angular.module('MyApp')
  .directive('navbar', function () {
    return {
      restrict: 'A',
      templateUrl : '/views/partials/nav.html',
      controller: function ($scope, ModalService) {
        $scope.ms = ModalService;
        $scope.songs = {};

        $scope.$watch('ms.songs', function(newVal, oldVal) {
          if(newVal != null) {
            $scope.$apply(function() {
              $scope.songs = newVal;
            });
          }
        });
          },
```

Comment: If the variable is bound to the controller, can't you $watch for changes from there?

Comment: I'm almost positive you can't watch values within a service like you're trying to do. Although if it's going to work, you're going to need the third argument for the $watch function, which is "true" for deep-level watching.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried this?

```
angular.module('MyApp')
  .directive('navbar', function () {
    return {
      restrict: 'A',
      templateUrl : '/views/partials/nav.html',
      controller: function ($scope, ModalService) {
        $scope.songs = ModalService.songs;
      }
  });
```

Answer (score 0):

I did run into a scenario recently where I had to setup a watch on a service property within a directive and the solution was to setup the watch within the link function similar to:

```
link: function(scope, element, attrs) {
    // other link code
    scope.$watch(function() { return svc.property; }, function(data) {
        // do something here
    });
    // other link code
}
```