# ng-class and ng-click not working

Tags: angularjs

I'm trying to use AngularJS to create a simple click to bold effect. I hope not to involve any controller scripts, but included or not, my code just don't work.

My HTML code with angular markup

```
<div ng-app="organHome">
    <dl class="sub-nav" ng-controller="inModalSwitchCtrl">
        <dd ng-class="content:bold"><a ng-click="switchContent()" ng-model="content">Contents</a>
        </dd>
        <dd ng-class="comment:bold"><a ng-model="comment" ng-click="switchComment()">Comments</a>
        </dd>
    </dl>
</div>
```

My js code:

```
angular.module('organHome', [])

    .controller('inModalSwitchCtrl', function ($scope) {
    $scope.content = true;
    $scope.comment = false;

    $scope.switchContent = function ($scope) {
        $scope.content = true;
        $scope.comment = false;
    };

    $scope.switchComment = function ($scope) {
        $scope.comment = true;
        $scope.content = false;
    };
});
```

Here is the example on fiddle

http://jsfiddle.net/qHkWA/

I know it must be very rookie-ish, but I'm stuck. Any help?

---

My original goal was to minimize my code, and hopefully no controller.js at all.

If there is anyway to just do it with existing directives, I would love to follow!

My horrible and not working approach looks like this:

```
<dl class="sub-nav">
    <dd ng-class="'active':content"><a ng-click="content = true" ng-model="content">Contents</a></dd>
    <dd ng-class="'active':comment"><a ng-model="comment">Comments</a></dd>
</dl>
```

Comment: Your jsfiddle example is throwing an error in the Chrome Console: `Uncaught Error: No module: organHome` I'm not sure if that is the root cause.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

in html:

```
    <dd ng-class="{'bold':content}"><a ng-click="switchContent()" ng-model="content">Contents</a></dd>

    <dd ng-class="{'bold':comment}"><a ng-model="comment" ng-click="switchComment()">Comments</a></dd>
```

Also Add css :

```
  .bold {font-weight: bold}
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/z7NJ7/1/)

**EDIT**

For less code, you can use this :

```
      <div ng-app="organHome">
         <dl class="sub-nav" ng-controller="inModalSwitchCtrl" ng-init="content=true">
            <dd ng-class="{'bold':content}"><a ng-click="content=true">Contents</a></dd>
            <dd ng-class="{'bold': !comment}"><a ng-click="content=false">Comments</a></dd>
         </dl>
     </div>
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/z7NJ7/1/)

Comment: may I ask does a writing like ng-init="content=true" normally work or not?

Answer (score 0):

Simplified syntax for ng-class is {value:expression} So your code would look like this:

```
<dd ng-class="{bold:content}"><a ng-click="switchContent()" ng-model="content">Contents</a></dd>
<dd ng-class="{bold:comment}"><a ng-model="comment" ng-click="switchComment()">Comments</a></dd>
```

Also you should select "No wrap in head". In your case angular did not even started.

Here is the working fiddle - http://jsfiddle.net/qHkWA/3/

Also for better understanding of how this work you may take a look at this thread - [What is the best way to conditionally apply a class?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7792652/what-is-the-best-way-to-conditionally-apply-a-class-with-angularjs)

And I don't know is it suits your purposes but you may simplify whole your code using jquery's toggleClass - http://jsfiddle.net/8kgMZ/3/ :

```
 <dd class="bold"><a ng-click="toggleBold()">Contents</a></dd>
 <dd><a ng-click="toggleBold()">Comments</a></dd>
```

and the controller:

```
  .controller('inModalSwitchCtrl', function ($scope) {
      $scope.toggleBold = function() {
          angular.element(document).find('dd').toggleClass('bold');
      };
```

Comment: When you said "No Wrap in Head" you were referring to the jsfiddle settings, correct?  When I try your sample I do not see it working.

Comment: it changing class when you click on that text, doesn't it?

Comment: I agree that toggle class might be a great solution at the time, but Angular's philosophy demands avoiding directly manipulation over DOM elements...that's the reason I try to use model value to control class behavior. Thank you for the jQuery code though!

Comment: You just see how my last fiddle is simplified compared to what you call is following angular's philosophy.