# $first in ngRepeat

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

I have an array `$scope.items`.

I want if the item is the `$first` one of the [ngRepeat](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.directive%3angRepeat) to add the css class `in`.

Is it something that can be done with angular? Generally how can I handle the booleans in Ajs?

```
<div ng-repeat="item in items">
   <div class='' > {{item.title}}</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 131, accepted):

It should be

```
<div ng-repeat="item in items">
   <div ng-class='{in:$first}' > {{item.title}}</div>
</div>
```

Look at `ng-class` directive in http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.directive:ngClass and in this thread [What is the best way to conditionally apply a class?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7792652/what-is-the-best-way-to-conditionally-apply-a-class-with-angularjs)

Comment: Can you explain how it should work? here is Fiddle where you can implement your way: http://jsfiddle.net/9Ymvt/673/   Thanks

Answer (score 3):

You can try approach with method invocation.

**HTML**

```
<div ng-controller = "fessCntrl"> 
<div ng-repeat="item in items">
   <div ng-class='rowClass(item, $index)' > {{item.title}}</div>   
</div>
</div>
```

**JS**

```
var fessmodule = angular.module('myModule', []);

fessmodule.controller('fessCntrl', function ($scope) {
   $scope.items = [
       {title: 'myTitle1', value: 'value1'},
       {title: 'myTitle2', value: 'value2'},
       {title: 'myTitle3', value: 'value1'},
       {title: 'myTitle4', value: 'value2'},
       {title: 'myTitle5', value: 'value1'}
   ];        

     $scope.rowClass = function(item, index){
         if(index == 0){
             return item.value;
         }
        return '';
    };        
});    
fessmodule.$inject = ['$scope'];
```

Demo <kbd>[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/9Ymvt/673/)</kbd>