# Set class in angular if variable is defined?

Tags: angularjs

I'm trying to set the class "expanded" to a div if the variable is undefined. I attempted this, but had no success. What am I doing wrong?

```
{'expanded': typeof member != 'undefined'}
```

Comment: Is it not the opposite that you are doing?

Comment: possible duplicate of [What is the best way to conditionally apply a class with angularjs?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7792652/what-is-the-best-way-to-conditionally-apply-a-class-with-angularjs)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can do it easier:

```
 ng-class="{'expanded':  member != undefined}"
```

or even:

```
ng-class="{'expanded':  member }"
```

Example: http://plnkr.co/edit/9RMulfYViGKf91743VZz?p=preview

Comment: A, didn't even read properly too see that the problem was that Kristoffer wasn't using ng-class. This is a better answer than mine :-)

Answer (score 2):

Place your condition inside a function in the scope.

Plunkr: http://plnkr.co/edit/JnH0H7