# Angular JS - Not setting class for bootstrap 3

Tags: angularjs, twitter-bootstrap

Following code is not working. It is supposed to show error or warning alert. Am I doing it correct?

```
<div ng-controller="HeaderController">
    <div ng-class='{alert-danger:show, warning:isWarning}' class="alert" ng-show="show">{{messageText}}</div>
    <button ng-click='showError()'>Simulate Error</button>
    <button ng-click='showWarning()'>Simulate Warning</button>
</div>

</div>
```

and

```
<script>

    var HeaderController = function ($scope) {
        $scope.isError = false;
        $scope.isWarning = false;
        $scope.show = false;

        $scope.showError = function () {
            $scope.messageText = 'This is an error!';
            $scope.isError = true;
            $scope.isWarning = false;
            $scope.show = true;
        };

    }
</script>
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [What is the best way to conditionally apply a class with angularjs?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7792652/what-is-the-best-way-to-conditionally-apply-a-class-with-angularjs)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should wrap the class, in `ng-class` with a single quotes:

```
<div ng-class="{'alert-danger':show, 'warning':isWarning}" class="alert" ng-show="show">{{messageText}}</div>
```

It was "documented" on a comment in the `ng-class` docs, but they removed the discuss from there.