# angularjs apply one class by ternary and another always

Tags: angularjs, glyphicons

I want to have the 'glyphicon' class on my icon tag always.
I want to have the 'glyphicon-plus' class when item.expanded is false, 'glyphicon-minus' class when item.expanded is true.

It seems there would be a simple way to do this but I've been unsuccessful using the ternary operator when I need another class to always be there.  The following code does not work.

```
<i ng-class="'glyphicon', (item.expanded) ? 'glyphicon-minus' : 'glyphicon-plus'"></i>
```

Comment: both of the answers below work.. which is the preferred angularjs way?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

ng-class don't really behave like this.

google says : [What is the best way to conditionally apply a class?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7792652/what-is-the-best-way-to-conditionally-apply-a-class-with-angularjs)

so an answer for your question could be :

```
<i class="glyphicon" ng-class="{'glyphicon-minus' : item.expanded, 'glyphicon-plus' : !item.expanded}"></i>
```