# How to toggle a glyphicon icon class?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap-3, glyphicons

I am working with AngularJs, Bootstrap 3. I want to toggle my glyphicon icon on my page. But i am able to do it. I  followed the response at the stackoverflow question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22940041/angularjs-apply-one-class-by-ternary-and-another-always).
I don't understand why i cannot display glyphicon with the toggle expression.

Here is my code :

```
<script>
    angular.module("myapp", [])
            .controller("MyController", function($scope) {
                $scope.toggleIcon = false;

                $scope.sort = function (sortBy) {
        $scope.toggleIcon = !$scope.toggleIcon;
                  // sorting logic
                };
            } );
</script>
</head>

<body ng-app="myapp">

<div ng-controller="MyController" >
    <div class="row">
         Here the name to sort
        <a href="" ng-click="sort('name')">Name </a><span class="glyphicon" ng-class="{glyphicon-sort-by-alphabet': toggleIcon, 'glyphicon-sort-by-alphabet-alt': !toggleIcon}"></span>
    </div>
        <div class="row">
         Here the icon
        <a href=""><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-sort-by-alphabet"></span></a>

    </div>
    </div>

</body>
</html>
```

You can see the code on [Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/NCuCdNrLs3FIoS5EYnOa?p=preview)

Thank you.

Comment: You have a typo `'glyphicon-sort-by-alphabet'` quotes missing. http://plnkr.co/edit/S6YnaR?p=preview. However you could do `{true : 'glyphicon-sort-by-alphabet' , false : 'glyphicon-sort-by-alphabet-alt'}[toggleIcon]` way as well..

Comment: Thanks. Post a response o will tick.