# Setting class to a variable in AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope

Sorry if this is very simply, i just started using angular yesterday.
I want to set a class of something to a variable, yet it isnt working.
This is what i've done:

```
<body ng-app="Witzle" ng-controller="BGController" class="{{bg.type}}">
```

and

```
app.controller('BGController',function($scope){
$scope.bg = {type:'witzle-bg-image'};
$scope.gah = function(name){
      alert(name)
      $scope.bg = {type:name};
 }
})
```

Ive run the code, and i know that $scope.gah() is being called because of the alert, but the class isnt being updated.

UPDATE: gah is already being called from somewhere else, my problem is that when it is called the class doesnt change

Comment: use ng-class https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngClass

Comment: possible duplicate of [What is the best way to conditionally apply a class with angularjs?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7792652/what-is-the-best-way-to-conditionally-apply-a-class-with-angularjs)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All you need is use ng-class directive without curly braces.

```
<body ng-app="Witzle" ng-controller="BGController" ng-class="bg.type">
```

please see demo:

http://jsbin.com/mesere/1/edit?html,css,js,output

Answer (score 0):

You need to apply ng-class. Created a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/74F7C/) to help you to start with coding

Code snippet:

```
<div ng-class="{abc: setThisClass}">
     TEST
</div>
```

[UPDATED FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/74F7C/1/)
To have the class set according to a variable string

Comment: I could do that, but there are a number of classes i want to switch between and that seems very inefficient, i would need a bool for each and an ng-class attribute for each, is there no way to do it with a variable string?