# Angular js scope variable inside ng-class?

Tags: angularjs

How add a scope variable inside ng-class ? is it possible to combine ng-class and class together with scope variable ?

I am building an accordion. So I need to have unique "isopen" class, say isopne1, isopen2, etc.. for each accordion to work.

```
<accordion-heading>
  {{list.name}}<i class="pull-right glyphicon" ng-class="{'icon-arrow-down-solid': isopen, 'icon-arrow-right-solid': !isopen}"></i>
</accordion-heading>
```

The above code is in ng-repeat. How can I set something like this

`ng-class="{'icon-arrow-down-solid': isopen{{list.value}}, 'icon-arrow-right-solid': !isopen{{list.value}}}"`

Comment: isopen{{set.value}} <--- surround your function with parenthesis

Comment: possible duplicate of [What is the best way to conditionally apply a class?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7792652/what-is-the-best-way-to-conditionally-apply-a-class)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
       <accordion close-others="oneAtATime">
        <accordion-group ng-repeat="set in sets" ng-init="status = $first" is-open="status" class="witlistcontents">
            <accordion-heading>
                Name <i class="pull-right glyphicon" ng-class="{'icon-arrow-down-solid': status, 'icon-arrow-right-solid': !status}"></i>
            </accordion-heading>
            <accordion-body>
            </accordion-body>
        </accordion-group>
       </accordion>
```

Correct way to givie icon class for accordion inside ng-repeat

Answer (score 1):

Use scope function

```
ng-class="{'icon-arrow-down-solid': isopen(set.value), 'icon-arrow-right-solid': is_not_open(set.value)}"
```

Answer (score 0):

your code itself will work fine depending upon the scope variable (isOpen flag) you want to add the css class to the "i" element correct.Create a scope variable (isOpen flag) in the controller.Then depending upon the isOpen flag automatically the icon will change