# How to set a class on a containing div

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

Hello and Thank You for looking at my problem. I am new to angularjs hence give me as much coaching as you would think I need.

I have 2 pages. 
(1) - singlepage.php (this one is really the main container for every other page
(2) - login.html (this one is really a fragment containing text boxes for username, password etc

`<!-- fragment from singlepage.php -->
<body ng-controller="AppController" class="{{bodyClass}}">
      <div id="view" ng-view></div>
</body>`

```
    $routeProvider.when('/login', {
        templateUrl: 'templates/login.html',
        bodyclass: 'login',
        controller: 'LoginController'
    });

    app.controller("LoginController", function($scope, $location, AuthenticationService, $route) {
    $scope.bodyclass = 'login';

    $scope.credentials = { email: "", password: "" };
    $scope.login = function() {
    AuthenticationService.login($scope.credentials).success(function() {
         $location.path('/home');
      });
    };
});
```

I need the class on body element to change to say "loginbox" when the login page loads.

Thanks Again

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Documentation for ng-class](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngClass)

ng-class="{bodyClass: true}"

Answer (score 1):

There are 2 references that may help you on your path:

1. The ngClass directive documentation - https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngClass#!
2. This here post: [What is the best way to conditionally apply a class?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7792652/what-is-the-best-way-to-conditionally-apply-a-class)

Answer (score 1):

You can use the $rootScope to set the view-model for elements of the template. 
For instance:

```
app.controller("LoginController", function($rootScope, $scope, $location, AuthenticationService, $route) {
  $rootScope.bodyClass = "loginbox";
  ...
});
```