# How to apply class to div dynamically using AngularJS

Tags: html, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap, ng-switch

I want to switch to div with class="col-md-x" depending upon the number of student object i am receiving. 
E.x: [Sample](http://jsfiddle.net/90jyghq6/)

1. if i am getting only one JSON object then i want to a div with class should be like(class="col-md-12").
2. if am getting two JSON object then i want to switch to a div with class="col-md-6".

```html
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-12">
            <div clss="row">
                <div ng-repeat="c in vm.students" class="col-md-12">
                    <div calss="thimbnail">
                        <div class="Option div 1">
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div ng-repeat="c in vm.students" class="col-md-6">
                    <div calss="thimbnail col-md-">
                        <div class="Option div 2">
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                 <div ng-repeat="c in vm.students" class="col-md-4">
                    <div calss="thimbnail col-md-">
                        <div class="Option div 3">
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: use ng-class and put condition inside that..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use ng-class like below,

```
ng-class="{class}[condition]"
In your case , 
ng-class="{1:'col-md-12', 2:'col-sm-6'}[vm.students.length]"
```

For your reference, [Detailed explanation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7792652/what-is-the-best-way-to-conditionally-apply-a-class)

Answer (score 0):

You have calss instead of class in the example code. I hope that is a typo.
To address to your problem you can make use of ng-class where you can assign classes based on conditions

More document on [ng-class](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngClass)

Code Snippet:

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-12">
            <div clss="row">
                <div ng-repeat="c in vm.students" ng-class="{col-md-12:vm.students.length === 1,col-md-6:vm.students.length === 2">
                    <div calss="thimbnail">
                        <div class="Option div 1">
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```