# ng-show and ng-if lags to hide content

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-scope, angular-ng-if, angularjs-ng-show

I have the following in to show and hide the clear button based upon if the searchQuery is empty or not. When a user starts typing in the input box, the button shows instantly.

However, when the user either clicks the clear button or deletes all input, there is a noticeable lag before the clear button is removed. I have tried ng-show as well, and have received the same results. Any ideas why this lag might exist?

HTML

```
<button ng-if="search.cardsQuery.length" class="button-icon" ng-click="clearSearchQuery()">
    <i class="ion-android-close search-cards"></i>
</button>
```

CONTROLLER

```
$scope.clearSearchQuery = function() {
    $scope.search.cardsQuery = '';
};
```

Comment: Could you reproduce a problem in jsfiddle?

Comment: Can you reproduce it here? http://plnkr.co/edit/8VvtrT7CfnZtj0iP5HmE?p=preview

Comment: Are you using ngAnimate or have any css transitions defined?

Comment: The answer exists at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7792652/what-is-the-best-way-to-conditionally-apply-a-class

Answer (score 4):

Check the css class on the element you're applying ng-if/ng-show to.  Look for the [transition effect](http://www.w3schools.com/css/css3_transitions.asp).  If the class has a transition, it may be the cause to the delay:

```
.button-icon {
    transition: all .5s;
}
```

Comment: transition: none !important; did the trick

Answer (score 0):

Its a common problem seen among the developers. Even trying with ng-if causes the same issue. I can suggest a simple solution for you.

Open your css file for the particular html file and add below line.

```
**.ng-hide { display: none !important }**
```

Hope, it will help.

Comment: Explain what exactly is the problem and how your solution will work.

Answer (score 0):

```
$scope.$evalAsync();
```

Worked for me :)