# angularJS changing background color of <td>

Tags: javascript, css, angularjs

So, I just need something like `this.style.backgroundColor = red;`
how do i write this in angular? `$scope.style.backgroundColor` didn't work, any other alternatives?

***EDIT:***

To clarify some things, i need to change the color on CLICK of a `<td>` element. it was easy to do in JS but now i need to do it dynamically in angular. So yeah, i don't see a way how ng-style can help me?

Comment: Have you looked at ngStyle https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngStyle?

Comment: just looking into it @JonC

Answer (score 1):

Since you're looking at presentation changes, you probably want to make the changes within the view, rather than within the controller.

[ng-style](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngStyle) will allow you to assign angularjs class objects which can be changed dynamically.

Here's an example from the documentation:

```
<input type="button" value="set color" ng-click="myStyle={color:'red'}">
<input type="button" value="set background" ng-click="myStyle={'background-color':'blue'}">
<input type="button" value="clear" ng-click="myStyle={}">
<br/>
<span ng-style="myStyle">Sample Text</span>
<pre>myStyle={{myStyle}}</pre>
```

**Edit:**

Here's how you can conditionally apply ng-style based upon function calls within your controller:

`<td ng-style="{ background-color: clicked ? 'red' : 'black' }">`

And, in your controller function:

`var $scope.clicked = false;
var ChangeColor = function($index){ $scope.clicked = true; }`

Note also that you can conditionally apply pre-defined style classes with ng-class, as well ([see this related question for examples](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7792652/664342)).

Comment: I don't think that this can help me, since i need it to be called in a function. 
like this: ` var ChangeColor = function($index){ //change color of element[$index] }`

Comment: That would have been helpful information to include in your original question...  I'll edit to address the new information.

Comment: @NeoChrome I've added examples for conditional style application through a controller function call.  I hope it helps.

Comment: Doesn't work.. and i know why, the $index is always the same for my `<td>` element, the object is created with ng-repeat so yeah.. is there a way to specify the HTML element index ? like $(this).find() in jquery?

Comment: Its hard to address without seeing the code, but you should be able to pass the instance from the ng-repeat directly into the function.  We're kind of veering into the topic of a different question altogether, but: `<td ng-repeat="bar in foo" ng-click="doSomething(bar)">` will let you call the function as `$scope.doSomething = function (bar) { ... }`

Comment: the function works! it is working but the angular table design is weird. the $index is 0 for the whole row where ever i click it is 0. thats the problem :/