# How to write conditional class directive using angularjs

Tags: angularjs

I have following directive like "pulsate" with restrict option class. I need to write condition like as below.

```
<div class="{pulsate : $index === 2}">
```

I tried this but its not working fine. So please help any one.

Comment: possible duplicate of [What is the best way to conditionally apply a class?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7792652/what-is-the-best-way-to-conditionally-apply-a-class)

Comment: Can you share a plunker/jsFiddle to demonstrate the problem?

Comment: ya sure.. i ll give.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use ng-class directive in order to achieve the solution.

```
<div ng-class="{pulsate : $index === 2}">
```

Comment: Yes, you need to add quotes around pulsate for angular to distinguish plain text from text with special meaning like directives.

Answer (score 0):

Use single commas around your class name like so:

```
<div ng-class="{'pulsate' : $index === 2}">
```