# Conditional class doesn't work with Bootstrap and Angular?

Tags: javascript, css, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap, angular-ui-bootstrap

Using [Bootstrap](http://getbootstrap.com/), [Angular](http://angularjs.org/) and [ui-bootstrap](https://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/) I'm creating a bunch of radio buttons which look like normal buttons ([working plunker here](http://plnkr.co/edit/sQB1hfS8Bdyv7eskcZTo?p=preview)).

I now want to make the active button blue (`.btn-primary`) and the rest white (`btn-default`). I found some SO-answers which explain how to conditionally apply a class [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7792652/what-is-the-best-way-to-conditionally-apply-a-class). I tried implementing this technique like so ([Plunker here](http://plnkr.co/edit/uBS8MsHJYbNxJ69WxMGt?p=preview)):

```
<div class="btn-group">
    <label class="btn" ng-class="{btn-primary: radioModel=='Left', btn-default: radioModel!='Left'}" ng-model="radioModel" btn-radio="'Left'">Left</label>
    <label class="btn" ng-class="{btn-primary: radioModel=='Middle', btn-default: radioModel!='Middle'}"ng-model="radioModel" btn-radio="'Middle'">Middle</label>
    <label class="btn" ng-class="{btn-primary: radioModel=='Right', btn-default: radioModel!='Right'}"ng-model="radioModel" btn-radio="'Right'">Right</label>
</div>
```

Unfortunately it doesn't seem to work. Does anybody know how I can achieve the active button to be a `btn-primary` and the other ones being a `btn-default`? All tips are welcome!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You are missing quotes around css classes `btn-primary` and `btn-default`. You need quotes because there is a dash in the property of the object.

See **[edited plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/p0gxEmNsazSx1JFlznTv?p=preview)**

Comment: One last question; is there a way that I can set the `btn-primary` class if the button is selected? That would save me to retype the model value twice in every button..

Comment: You could define all buttons as `btn btn-default` and add the class `btn-primary` when needed using `ng-class` (see [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/HZs6qa1eZqTsuxD8coiF?p=preview)). But actually, if you add css styles for the `.btn.active`, you could get rid of the `ng-class` directive: indeed, you want to style the *active* button and so far you do that by changing his type from *default* to *primary* (see [yet another plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/Xy1MK6SFUpa49lHe8LJP?p=preview))