# Angularjs add bootstrap classes dynamically using directive

Tags: javascript, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap, angularjs-directive

We are implementing reusable code in our application for this purpose we have created a simple directive which displays content.

Directive Code:

```
angular.module("newsStore.moduleDirectives", [])
    .directive('renderAboutContent', ['aboutService', renderAboutContent]);

function renderAboutContent(aboutService) {
    return {
        restrict: 'AE',
        scope: {},
        templateUrl: 'templates/about.html',
        link: function (scope, element) {
            aboutService.getAboutContent()
                .then(function (results) {
                    scope.aboutList = results.aboutContent.listItems;
                }, function (error) {
                    console.log('controller error', error);
                });
        }
    }
}
```

HTML code:

```
<div class="col-md-12 aboutUs-ph padT10 content-ph_abt" ng-repeat="content in aboutList">
    <div class="col-md-2 form-group" ng-if="content.image">
        <img src="{{content.image}}" class="img-responsive" />
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-9">
        <span class="guidedTourText"><b>{{content.title}}</b></span>
        <br>
        <span>{{content.description}}</span>
    </div>
</div>
```

Question:

In the above HTML you can see col-md-2 and col-md-9 inside col-md-12, let's say I have three div elements, and three of them occupies 4, 4 ,4 if the content is present. Let's say if the content is not present in the last div then the remaining two div's should take 6,6 and vice versa. We want this to be implemented from the directive.

Let me know if I am not clear.

Comment: I would set up a $watch inside of your link function. The $watch would monitor a function, and that function would look for DOM changes (i.e. DIV children changes). Depending on the state of the DOM, then dynamically add the col-* attributes.

Comment: Thanks for the comment @pixelbits, but I am new to angular js , can you show me how to implement the above $watch in my directive.

Comment: did u tried ng-class? check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7792652/what-is-the-best-way-to-conditionally-apply-a-class & https://scotch.io/tutorials/the-many-ways-to-use-ngclass.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would set up a $watch inside of your link function. The $watch would monitor a function, and that function would look for DOM changes (i.e. DIV children changes). Depending on the state of the DOM, then dynamically add the col-* attributes

**Directive**

```
app.directive('bootstrapColumns', function() {
    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        link: function(scope, element, attr) {
            if (!element.hasClass('row'))
                element.addClass('row');


            scope.$watch(function() {
                var elems = element[0].childNodes;
                var count =0;
                angular.forEach(elems, function(e) {

                    if (e.tagName == 'DIV' && angular.element(e).text() != '')
                        ++count;
                });
                return count;
            },
            function(cols) {
                var colNum = 12 / cols;
                var cssClass = 'col-xs-' + colNum;
                var elems = element[0].childNodes;
                angular.forEach(elems, function(e) {
                    if (e.tagName == 'DIV') {
                        var div = angular.element(e);                  
                        if (div.text() != '' && !div.hasClass(cssClass))
                            div.addClass(cssClass);
                    }
                });
            });
        }
    }
});
```

**HTML**

```
<div bootstrap-columns>
   <div>Column1</div>
   <div>Column2</div>  
</div>
```

[Demo Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/8nmhvgnj/10/)

Comment: thanks for the answer, I just have one quick question, I am trying to use your solution in my application.I have followed your example. 
<div bootstrap-columns>
   <div>Column1
       <div>column1-child</div>
   </div>
   <div>Column2</div>  
</div>
In the above example the col-md width applies for the inner child div too, we don't want the child div's affecting only the parent div should have the width. Can you tell me how to avoid the child div's from this?

Comment: Updated to only look at immediate child DIVs

Comment: Thanks for the answer bro @pixelbits, one last question I know this lot, as my Project lead keeps on changing the requirement :). Here is the question
<div bootstrap-columns>
   <div>Column1</div>
   <div>Column2</div>  
   <div>Column3</div>
</div>
In this case he wants the first and last div to take the width as col-md-3 and the middle as col-md-6, so if the any one of the first and last are not present the middle one takes col-md-9 and the other takes col-md-3.

Answer (score 1):

I'm giving you a generic usage, you can easily write it with your content. Suppose you have three variables available in your scope: `content`, `content2` and `content3`. Now you can write like this:

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-6" ng-class="{'col-md-4': content3}">{{content1}}</div>
    <div class="col-md-6" ng-class="{'col-md-4': content3}">{{content2}}</div>
    <div class="col-md-4" ng-show="content3">{{content3}}</div>
</div>
```

So what is happening here is, by default the `col-md-6` will be given to the columns and if there is there is content in the 3rd column then we will also the class `col-md-4` so that all three columns can be equally divided. `col-md-4` will take precedence over `col-md-6`.

Or, if you want more clearance, you can simply write this also:

```
<div class="row">
    <div ng-class="{'col-md-4': content3, 'col-md-6': !content3}">{{content1}}</div>
    <div ng-class="{'col-md-4': content3, 'col-md-6': !content3}">{{content2}}</div>
    <div class="col-md-4" ng-show="content3">{{content3}}</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

As a follow up to using `ng-class`, you can also use a function that returns the class:

```js
var app = angular.module('app', []);

app.directive('aboutDirective', function renderAboutContent(aboutService) {
  return {
    restrict: 'AE',
    scope: {},
    templateUrl: 'about.html',
    link: function(scope, element) {
      aboutService.getAboutContent()
        .then(function(results) {
          scope.aboutList = results.aboutContent.listItems;
        }, function(error) {
          console.log('controller error', error);
        });
      scope.colWidth = function(content) {
        return content.image && content.something ? 'col-xs-4' : 'col-xs-6';
      }
    }
  }
});

app.factory('aboutService', function($timeout) {
  return {
    getAboutContent: function() {
      return $timeout(function() {
        return {
          aboutContent: {
            listItems: [{
              image: 'image1',
              title: 'title1',
              description: 'desc1',
              something: 'something1'
            }, {
              image: 'image2',
              title: 'title2',
              description: 'desc2'
            }, {
              title: 'title3',
              description: 'desc3',
              something: 'something3'
            }]
          }
        };
      }, 1000);
    }
  };
});
```

```css
.row {
  display: flex;
  text-align: center;
  color: #fff;
}
.image {
  background-color: #75b5aa;
  border: 1px solid #000;
}
.middle {
  background-color: #aa759f;
  border: 1px solid #000;
}
.something {
  background-color: #6a9fb5;
  border: 1px solid #000;
}
```

```html
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.4/jquery.js"></script>
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.15/angular.min.js"></script>
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.5/js/bootstrap.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.css">

<div class="container" ng-app='app'>
  <about-directive></about-directive>
  
  <script type="text/ng-template" id="about.html">
    <div class="row" ng-repeat="content in aboutList">
      <div ng-if="content.image" class="image" ng-class="colWidth(content)">
        {{ content.image }}
      </div>
      <div class="middle" ng-class="colWidth(content)">
        <span><b>{{content.title}}</b></span>
        <br>
        <span>{{content.description}}</span>
      </div>
      <div ng-if="content.something" class="something" ng-class="colWidth(content)">
        {{content.something}}
      </div>
    </div>
  </script>
</div>
```