# How to apply other css class if first css class is not there?

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework, css-sprites, sprite-sheet

i am using Image sprites.Some Image sprites CSS class:

```
.icon-ONE {
  background-image: url(../img/spritesheet.png);
  background-position: -32px 0px;
  width: 32px;
  height: 32px;
}
.icon-TWO {
  background-image: url(../img/spritesheet.png);
  background-position: -288px -288px;
  width: 32px;
  height: 32px;
}
.icon-NOIMAGE {
  background-image: url(../img/spritesheet.png);
  background-position: 0px -32px;
  width: 32px;
  height: 32px;
}
```

HTML :

```
 <div ng-repeat="product in products">
      <div ng-show="product.type!=''" class="icon-{{product.type | removeSpace | uppercase}} " ></div>
      <div ng-show="!product.type || product.type==''" class=" icon-NOIMAGE" ></div>
 </div>
```

so,if "product.type" is something different,it should apply class icon-NOIMAGE.

i have tried using ng-class [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7792652/what-is-the-best-way-to-conditionally-apply-a-class) but it didnt work.as their is no condition to check.need to find if css class exist.
have tried :

```
angular.element(myElement).hasClass('my-class');
```

One of the solution : by adding icon-NOIMAGE class.but it failed in some conditions.

```
 <div ng-show="product.type!=''" class="icon-{{product.type | removeSpace | uppercase}} icon-NOIMAGE" ></div>
```

is their any way to check if css class exists.?

is their any different way for this,i can do..?

Answer (score 2):

If you want apply class conditionally you should use ng-class.

```
ng-class="{'yourclass' : variable == 'value'}"
```

Comment: can u apply your ans to my ques..?Explain more..!i have tried ng-class..!