# Change class with AngularJS

Tags: html, angularjs, asp.net-mvc, angular-ng-if

I have this piece of code in a ASP.NET MVC view:

```
<div ng-repeat="it in (@source)">
            <button class="btn hvr-glow btn-success" >
                {{it.name}}
                <p ng-if="it.check==true"><i class="fa fa-check-circle-o" ng-click="it.check=false"></i></p>
                <p ng-if="it.check==false'"><i class="fa fa-circle-o" ng-click="it.check=true"></i></p>       
            </button>                               
        </div>
```

source is a list of objects of type ApplicationStatus, which contain a boolean field named check. I want to change the type of the font awesome icon on click. But I don't see the icons. Source is correctly loaded. Where is the problem ?

Answer (score 1):

You can use `ng-class` for that. For example:

```
<i ng-class="{'fa fa-check-circle-o': check, 'fa fa-circle-o': !check}"
```

Here's another question related to [ng-class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7792652/what-is-the-best-way-to-conditionally-apply-a-class)

Note - a ternary operator would probably be best in your case

Comment: Ok but I also want to change check on click

Answer (score 0):

```
<div ng-repeat="it in source">
  <button class="btn hvr-glow btn-success" ng-click="it.check = !it.check">
          {{it.name}}
      <p>
        <i ng-class="{'fa fa-check-circle-o': it.check, 'fa fa-circle-o': !it.check}"></i>
      </p>
  </button>
 </div>
```