# Polymer add class when property is true

Tags: polymer

I have seen this in angular before and wondered if this is possible in polymer as well. [Angular - What is the best way to conditionally apply a class?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7792652/what-is-the-best-way-to-conditionally-apply-a-class)

I have set up a property named 'animated':

```
animated: {
  type: Boolean,
  value: false,
},
```

When animated is true, a div inside my element should have a css class of **.animate**.

```
<div class=""></div>
```

For now I have done that inside of the ready function.
But since I came across that Stackoverflow question I wondered if this is prossible in polymer.

Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

One way to do that is using a function as follow:

```
<div class$="{{_getClass(animated)}}"></div>
```

Where `class$` with `$` symbol indicates to Polymer's that property is generate using data binding. So, your `_getClass` function will look like this:

```
_getClass: function(animated){
   return animated ? "animate" : "";
}
```

When `animate` property changes, the `_getClass` function will be invoked and this function will return the string that indicates the class you need.

Answer (score 2):

You can also use [toggleClass](https://www.polymer-project.org/1.0/docs/api/Polymer.Base#method-toggleClass) method of `Polymer`

```html
<base href="https://polygit.org/components/">
<script src="webcomponentsjs/webcomponents-lite.min.js"></script>
<link rel="import" href="polymer/polymer.html">
<dom-module id="my-element">
  <template>
    <style>
      .show {
        display: block !important;
        border: 1px solid black;
      }
      .hide {
        width: 100px;
        height: 100px;
        display: none;
      }
    </style>
    <div class="hide" id="toggle"></div>
    <button on-tap="_toggleDiv">Press to toggle</button>
  </template>
</dom-module>
<script>
  Polymer({
    is: 'my-element',
    properties: {
      show: {
        type: Boolean,
        value: false
      }
    },
    _toggleDiv: function() {
      this.show = !this.show;
      this.toggleClass('show', this.show, this.$.toggle);
    }
  });
</script>

<my-element></my-element>
```

Comment: `Uncaught TypeError: this.toggleClass is not a function`

Comment: @Metagrapher Polymer version?